# How to set background color of a View

Tags: android, view, colors, background, set

I'm trying to set the background color of a View (in this case a Button).

I use this code:

```
// set the background to green
v.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF00 );
v.invalidate();
```

It causes the Button to disappear from the screen.   What am I doing wrong, and what is the correct way to change the background color on any View?

Thanks.

Comment: That looks correct.  In fact, I don't think you need to call invalidate().  When you say the button disappears, do you mean that literally or do you mean the button had text or an image on it that disappears?

Answer (score 300, accepted):

You made your button transparent. The first byte is the alpha.

Try `v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);`

Comment: EddieB's answer below is much better as this removes any borders etc. such as an EditText's underlining

Comment: @aroth is better Color.Green ? If I want color complext with argb ? ... your answer is deprecated

Comment: @delive - Come again?  [Color.GREEN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#GREEN) is _not_ deprecated, and includes the alpha byte.  It's value is `0xff00ff00`, _exactly_ the same as what's suggested in the answer, except it also has the benefit of being _human-readable_.  Most developers would prefer a human-readable solution.

Comment: What do you write between the brackets when you want to refer to a color in your colors.xml?

Answer (score 153):

When you call setBackgoundColor it overwrites/removes any existing background resource, including any borders, corners, padding, etc.
What you want to do is change the color of the existing background resource...

```
View v;
v.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
```

Experiment with PorterDuff.Mode.* for different effects.

Comment: "overwrites/removes any existing background resource," not really.

Comment: I had to use the above along with v.invalidate(); on the next line.

Comment: tried this wasted time and went with the accepted answer, v.getBackground() gave nullpointer exception and crashed.

Comment: This plus PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN solved for me so I wouldn't lose my background border.

Answer (score 144):

Several choices to do this...

**Set background to green:**

```
v.setBackgroundColor(0x00FF00);
```

**Set background to green with [Alpha](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html):**

```
v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
```

**Set background to green with Color.GREEN constant:**

```
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

**Set background to green defining in [Colors.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>     
    <color name="myGreen">#00FF00</color> 
    <color name="myGreenWithAlpha">#FF00FF00</color> 
</resources>
```

and using:

```
v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.myGreen);
```

and:

```
v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.myGreenWithAlpha);
```

or the longer winded:

```
v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.myGreen));
```

and:

```
v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.myGreenWithAlpha));
```

Comment: `getResources().getColor(...)` got deprecated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842983/getresources-getcolor-is-deprecated

Comment: There's also: `v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.myGreen);` when using `colors.xml`

Comment: Removed the `invalidate` calls, as you can [see](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/view/View.java#View.setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) `setBackground...` methods already call that.

Comment: `v.setBackgroundColor(0x00FF00);` is just their code which they say isn't working. I would also expect it to be transparent.

Answer (score 40):

You can set the hex-color to any resource with:

```
View.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e7eecc"));
```

Answer (score 16):

```
// set the background to green
v.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF00 );
v.invalidate();
```

The code does not set the button to green. Instead, it makes the button totally invisible.

Explanation: the hex value of the color is wrong. With an Alpha value of zero, the color will be invisible.

The correct hex value is `0xFF00FF00` for full opacity green. Any Alpha value between 00 and FF would cause transparency.

Answer (score 14):

For setting the first color to be seen on screen, you can also do it in the relevant layout.xml (better design) by adding this property to the relevant View:

```
android:background="#FF00FF00"
```

Comment: The question makes clear that the color change needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 12):

> and what is the correct way to change
>   the background color on any View?

On *any* `View`? What you have is correct, though you should drop the `invalidate()` call.

However, some `Views` already have backgrounds. A `Button`, for example, already has a background: the face of the button itself. This background is a `StateListDrawable`, which you can find in `android-2.1/data/res/drawable/btn_default.xml` in your Android SDK installation. That, in turn, refers to a bunch of nine-patch bitmap images, available in multiple densities. You would need to clone and modify all of that to accomplish your green goals.

In short, you will be better served finding another UI pattern rather than attempting to change the background of a `Button`.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation about Button backgrounds.  Nine patch bitmaps (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html) were new to me.

I simply want to change the color of anything on the screen when I press a Button.  The Buttons are on a TextView.  Trying to change the color of that, leads to console messages "DDM dispatch reg wait timeout... ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 52454151: no handler defined" and a dialog on screen "the app stopped unexpectedly".

Guess I need to do more reading on the UI.  Any hints welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

try to add:

```
setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
```

Answer (score 7):

I use at API min 16 , target 23

```
Button WeekDoneButton = (Button) viewWeeklyTimetable.findViewById(R.id.week_done_button);

WeekDoneButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorAccent));
```

Answer (score 7):

This works for me

```
v.getBackground().setTint(Color.parseColor("#212121"));
```

That way only changes the color of the background without change the background itself. This is usefull for example if you have a background with rounded corners.

Answer (score 6):

```
mButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simple use :

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simple use :

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 198, 255));
```

Answer (score 4):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748830/how-to-change-background-color-in-android-app) talks about changing the background color of a view. In one of the answers, the person explains how to change the background color during runtime. Obviously you are going to look into how to modify other objects on the screen, but this should give you a good start by at least allowing you to modify the background color of the view on button click.

Answer (score 4):

Stating with Android 6 use ContextCompact

```
        view.setBackgroundColor( ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.your_color));
```

Answer (score 2):

In **kotlin** you could do it like this:

```
val backgroundColor = R.color.whatever_color_you_like
view.setBackgroundColor(getColorCompat(backgroundColor))
```

Where `getColorCompat()` is an extension function:

```
/**
 * Extension method to provide simpler access to {@link ContextCompat#getColor(int)}.
 */

 fun Context.getColorCompat(color: Int) = ContextCompat.getColor(this, color)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
view.setBackgroundColor(R.color.primaryColor);
```

Adds color to previous color value, so i have a different color.

What works for me is :

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.primaryColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let suppose we have a **primary color** in `values=>colors.xml` as:

```
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#FDD835</color>
</resources>
```

so if we want to use our custom color into `setBackgroundColor(@ColorInt int Color)` then we just need an annotation **`@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")`** with constructor/method which will be used as:

```
    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    public _LinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Formatting our layout : )
        super.setBackgroundColor(R.color.primary);

        ....


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass an `int` in the argument.

First Example:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(-500136)
```

Second Example:

```
int colorId = R.color.green;

view.setBackgroundResource(colorId);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine: `v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);`

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above ways. But I havent achieve what i need. Here is my try.
If you are using hexcode for color and want to set the color as background of image, then this is the kotlin code.

```
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(30, 30, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
val colorCode = "#ffffff"
canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor(colorCode))
mImageViewLogo.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling setBackgroundColor on a view you need to set the alpha value to a non-zero value (e.g. 0xFF), otherwise the color will not show up.

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextview);
int rgb = 0xF05922; // Orange
tv.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000|rgb); // Use bitwise OR to add alpha to RGB value
```