# How to Change color of button to its default color

Tags: android, button

I am creating a MCQ application in which there are four option `Buttons`.Initially all the buttons's color is default color.Whenever user clicks on correct answer background color of the `Button` changes to green and when user clicks on wrong option Background color of the `Button` changes to red and display correct answer `Button` in green. After that user clicks on next question button. Now I want to change the background color of all the option`Buttons` to its initial state i.e default color. I don't know how to do it. Please help me in changing the Button image to its default color/image.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the onClick() of the NEXT BUTTON place a the code to change the option button colors to the colors of your choice.

```
 onClick()
{
 button.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

The default color is not a color, it is StateListDrawable of many 9-patch images
I suggest you set the background of buttons to be white for option buttons and then set it back to white when NEXT button is pressed.

Comment: can you help me in getting the default color id of the button

Comment: The background of a button is not a color its a StateListDrawable of many 9-patch images

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401009/how-to-gradient-fill-a-buttons-background

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color

Comment: Thanks, I don't have much idea about using 9-patch images.But those links were helpful I will try.