# How to set the text color of TextView in code?

Tags: android, colors, textview

In XML, we can set a text color by the `textColor` attribute, like `android:textColor="#FF0000"`. But how do I change it by coding?

I tried something like:

```
holder.text.setTextColor(R.color.Red);
```

Where `holder` is just a class and `text` is of type `TextView`. Red is an RGB value (#FF0000) set in strings.

But it shows a different color rather than red. What kind of parameter can we pass in setTextColor()? In documentation, it says `int`, but is it a resource reference value or anything else?

Comment: A note about tweaking UI in code, please consider the advantages of seeing the UI in design time, minimizing the runtime changes to minimum.

Answer (score 1375, accepted):

You should use:

```
holder.text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

---

You can use various functions from the `Color` class to get the same effect of course.

- `Color.parseColor` [(Manual)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)) (like LEX uses)

  ```
  text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
  ```
- `Color.rgb` and `Color.argb` ([Manual rgb](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#rgb%28int,%20int,%20int%29%29)) ([Manual argb](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)) (like Ganapathy uses)

  ```
  holder.text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(200,0,0));
  holder.text.setTextColor(Color.argb(0,200,0,0));
  ```
- And of course, if you want to define your color in an `XML` file, you can do this:

  ```
  <color name="errorColor">#f00</color>
  ```

  because the `getColor()` function is deprecated<sup>1</sup>, you need to use it like so:

  ```
  ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
  ```
- You can also insert plain HEX, like so:

  ```
  myTextView.setTextColor(0xAARRGGBB);
  ```

  Where you have an alpha-channel first, then the color value.

Check out the complete manual of course, *[public class Color extends Object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)*.

---

<sup>1</sup>This code used to be in here as well:

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorColor));
```

This method is now deprecated in Android M. You can however use it from the [contextCompat in the support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590714/getcolorint-id-deprecated-on-android-6-0-marshmallow-api-23), as the example now shows.

Comment: In addition, if the text is a link you need to use text.setLinkTextColor(...); in code or android:textColorLink="..." in XML

Comment: @Nanne It would be nice if your answer also mentioned that R.color.XXX is a reference to the color. Meaning that it needs to be dereferenced (as it is in your example), for clarity.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? As in, dereferenced and so will use more resources or do you mean something else?

Comment: Is there any way of telling if a particular color value is going to let a text disappear?

Comment: `getColor(int)` is deprecated.

Comment: @AlwinKesler I'm not really sure what you mean by posting that link. **It was allready in the answer, in code and as a link**. I did change it a bit because it seems that it wasn't clear enough, so maybe this is better?

Comment: Sorry, I want's clear enough. On Android 6.0 (API 23) `getResource().getColor()` is deprecated. Consider using `ContextCompat.getColor()` instead

Comment: textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorWhite));
Add below line in colors.xml.
<color name="colorWhite">#FFFFFF</color>

Comment: how did to import color class?

Comment: More codes about color codes in Android studio  https://encycolorpedia.com/a4c639

Comment: Fun Fact: You can't set an Emoji's color, even though it's a member of your font. Call all the other glyphs "inked," and changing the color changes their ink. But all Emojis come with their own specified colors (which hopefully work on both light and dark backgrounds), so setTextColor() just bounces off them.

Answer (score 149):

If you still want to specify your colors in your XML file:

```
<color name="errorColor">#f00</color>
```

Then reference it in your code with one of these two methods:

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorColor, getResources().newTheme()));
```

or

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorColor, null));
```

The first is probably preferable if you're compiling against Android M, however the theme you pass in can be null, so maybe that's easier for you?

And if you're using the Compat library you can do something like this

```
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.errorColor));
```

Comment: For setTextColor, why does it have to take the getResources().getColor() rather than the direct R.color.errorColor reference?  The R.color.x works for almost every other method.  Incredibly frustrating!

Comment: @Civilian: because the int param that the setXXXColor() methods require is taken as the actual ARGB value to use, NOT the value to lookup in the resources file. Strangely enough, the View class has both setBackgroundColor() and setBackgroundResource(), while TextView is missing a setTextResource() method.

Comment: `getColor(int)` is deprecated. `ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.yourColor);` seems to be the replacement.

Answer (score 55):

And another one:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Comment: `getResources()` is a Context member function. For adapters, use `getContext().getResources()`. Color values should go into resources, like in @xbakesx's answer.

Answer (score 44):

You can do this only from an XML file too.

Create a `color.xml` file in the values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="textbody">#ffcc33</color>

</resources>
```

Then in any XML file, you can set color for text using,

```
android:textColor="@color/textbody"
```

Or you can use this color in a Java file:

```
final TextView tvchange12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
//Set color for textbody from color.xml file
tvchange1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textbody));
```

Answer (score 29):

You can use

```
holder.text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(200,0,0));
```

You can also specify what color you want with Transparency.

```
holder.text.setTextColor(Color.argb(0,200,0,0));
```

**a for Alpha** (Transparent) value r-red  g-green  b-blue

Answer (score 19):

use the following code in layout.xml

```
<TextView  android:id="@+id/textView1"    
android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/add"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:textAppearance="?
android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:textColor="#25383C"
android:textSize="13sp" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#25383C"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
```

Answer (score 16):

There are many different ways to set color on text view.

1. Add color value in studio res->values->colors.xml as

   ```
   <color name="color_purple">#800080</color>
   ```

   Now set the color in xml or actvity class as

   ```
   text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_purple)
   ```
2. If you want to give color code directly use below Color.parseColor code

   ```
   textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
   ```
3. You can also use RGB

   ```
   text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(200,0,0));
   ```
4. Use can also use direct hexcode for textView. You can also insert plain HEX, like so:

   ```
   text.setTextColor(0xAARRGGBB);
   ```
5. You can also use argb with alpha values.

   ```
      text.setTextColor(Color.argb(0,200,0,0));
   ```

   a for Alpha (Transparent) v.
6. And if you're using the Compat library you can do something like this

   ```
      text.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_purple));
   ```

Answer (score 10):

```
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationC‌​ontext(),R.color.col‌​orWhite));
```

In the `colors.xml` file, write in the code below:

```
<color name="colorWhite">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Answer (score 9):

I normally do this for any views:

```
myTextView.setTextColor(0xAARRGGBB);
```

where

- AA defines alpha (00 for transparent, FF for opaque)
- RRGGBB defines the normal HTML color code (like FF0000 for red).

Comment: And why the down-vote? Can you add some thoughts on this please?

Answer (score 7):

If you plan to use **setTextAppearance** you should know that it will overwrite the text color with the style inherited from the theme. So if you want to use both, set the color **afterwards**.

This works:

```
textView.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

While this will cause your textcolor to be for instance white(for dark theme) or black(for the light theme):

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
textView.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
```

Contrary to this in XML the order is arbitrary.

Answer (score 7):

`text.setTextColor(getResource().getColor(R.color.black))` you have create black color in color.xml.

OR

`text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))` here type desired hexcode

OR

`text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)` you can use static color fields

Answer (score 6):

I believe that if you want to specify a color as a resource (in the [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) file), you'll have to provide its [ARGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space#ARGB) value (not simply the RGB value).

Try changing your color value to `#FFFF0000`. It should give you RED.

Comment: to my experience, that's not true and it is possible to use a RGB  value instead of a ARGB value

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(285,0,0));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
holder.text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(200,0,0));
```

or

```
myTextView.setTextColor(0xAARRGGBB);
```

Answer (score 5):

## Kotlin Extension Solution

Add these to make changing text color simpler

#### For setting ColorInt

```
myView.textColor = Color.BLACK // or Color.parseColor("#000000"), etc.

var TextView.textColor: Int
get() = currentTextColor
set(@ColorInt color) {
    setTextColor(color)
}
```

#### For setting ColorRes

```
myView.setTextColorRes(R.color.my_color)

fun TextView.setTextColorRes(@ColorRes colorRes: Int) {
    val color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes)
    setTextColor(color)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you use **Kotlin**, there are 4 ways: (with Holder)

1. Use **Android resource**:

   holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
2. Use **RGB**:

   holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 87, 34))

3)Use **Hex**:

```
holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#C2185B"))
```

4)Use **Project resource**: (requires API level 23)

```
holder.textView.setTextColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.colorMax,null))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Adapter you can set the text color by using this code:

```
holder.text_view = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
holder.text_view.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF00FF"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
text1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Comment: [ask questions wisely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479689/opencv-in-android-application-image-blur-detection)  :)

Answer (score 3):

```
TextView text = new TextView(context);
text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("any hex value of a color"));
```

Above code is working on my side. Here `text` is a **TextView** on which color is needed to be set.

Answer (score 2):

From API 23 onward, `getResources().getColor()` is deprecated.

Use this instead:

```
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.color_black));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Adapter you can set the text color by using this code:

```
holder.my_text_view = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
holder.my_text_view.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   textViewStatus.setTextColor(res.getColor(R.color.green));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to give color code directly then use

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

or if you want to give color code from colors folder then use

```
textView.setTextColor(R.color.white);
```

Comment: this code textView.setTextColor(R.color.white); doesn't work. You could use text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_purple) for getting the color from your color.xml

Answer (score 1):

I did this way:
Create a XML file, called Colors in res/values folder.

My Colors.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="vermelho_debito">#cc0000</color>
    <color name="azul_credito">#4c4cff</color>
    <color name="preto_bloqueado">#000000</color>
    <color name="verde_claro_fundo_lista">#CFDBC5</color>
    <color name="branco">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="amarelo_corrige">#cccc00</color>
    <color name="verde_confirma">#66b266</color>
</resources>
```

To get this colors from the xml file, I've used this code:
 valor it's a TextView, and ctx it's a Context object. I'm not using it from an Activity, but a BaseAdapter to a ListView. That's why I've used this Context Object.

```
valor.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.azul_credito));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set color of a TextView, `TextView.setTextColor(R.color.YOURCOLOR)` is not enough!

It has to be used like this –

```
TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.YoutTextViewID);

myText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YOURCOLOR);
```

OR

```
myText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#54D66A"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
holder.userType.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.green));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorColor, null));
```

Comment: it was mentioned above, but it bears repeating here:  getColor is deprecated as of android M.  It may disappear some day.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview );
textview .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#85F85F"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I know there are many questions and it's late to answer this now but just to help someone who is stuck like me:

#### If you get an error Cannot resolve symbol Color

You have to `import android.graphics.Color` and then `txt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))`

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, I was using `color.xml`:

```
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
```

For setting the `TextView` background like:

```
textView.setTextColor(R.color.white);
```

I was getting a different color, but when I used the below code I got the actual color.

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff6363"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For providing rgb values: `text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(200,0,0));`
For parsing the color from a hex value:
`text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)` to use any of the in-built colors of the `Color` class.

You can also use `textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(hexRGBvalue))` to define custom colors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an adapter and still want to use a color defined in resources you can try the following approach:

```
holder.text.setTextColor(holder.text.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.myRed));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textresult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textresult.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

getColor() is depreceted

So try this way:

```
 tv_title.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.sf_white));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this for a TextView in a ViewHolder for a RecyclerView. I'm not so sure why, but it didn't work for me in the ViewHolder initialization.

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor));
    // Other stuff
}
```

But when I moved it to the onBindViewHolder, it worked fine.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){
    // Other stuff
    holder.textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor));
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView color= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.color);
text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { 
    b.numberDay1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.secondary_100))
} else {                
    b.numberDay1.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.secondary_100))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me inside of recycler View adapter (Compile API = 33):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
.
.
.

holder.view.myTextView.setTextColor(holder.itemView.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following code :

```
holder.text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("F00"));
```