# How to change color for item selected in Gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

I've done a Gallery view composed by just textviews as numbers. By default if I don't set any colors the item in the centre is black. I want to change it.

Using a selector it doesn't work, any ideas?

UPDATE:
if I try to use a selector also the default behavior gone and I can see only grey textview

So, this is the getVIew of my TextAdapter that extends BaseAdapter

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView t = new TextView(mContext);
            int val = position + 1;
            t.setText("" + val);
            t.setTextSize(30f);
            t.setTextColor(R.drawable.numericgallery_selector);

            return t;
 }
```

and this is my selector.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#FDF132"></item>

    <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="#CADDCD"></item>

    <item android:color="#FFFFFF"></item>
</selector>
```

but it doen't work.... :(

Comment: See [this][1] answer, it tells you how to set the color in code.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-text-color-of-textview-by-coding

Comment: thanks jack but this isn't what I want, sorry.

Comment: What color is the item in the center using this code?

Comment: a kind of dark grey... but none of the colors I set...

Comment: Is it the BACKGROUND color you want to change, or the text color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my old post with no solution.
So I tell you how I worked it out.

```
t.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.drawable.numericgallery_selector));
```

Answer (score 0):

Inflate the TextView to use inside the gallery. Then it does  not require to change any thing dynamically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    **android:textColor="@drawable/tracker_selected_color"**
    android:id="@+id/textview_tracker_item" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />
```

and then try 
tracker_selected_color.xml

```
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#FDF132"></item>

<item android:state_selected="false" android:color="#CADDCD"></item>

<item android:color="#FFFFFF"></item>
```