# Text of Android button isn't displayed in the specified colour

Tags: android, button, text, spannable

I have a pretty simple problem. I'm creating several buttons with a method in an activity. However the text colour just remains in the standard colour (grey). I defined the following in my method:

```
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setTextColor(R.color.red);
b.setText("Some text");
```

Is anyone aware of this problem and can help me out? By googling I read sth. about spannable. However it seems that this isn't working with the text of buttons.

Comment: Several ways to skin this cat - nice answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-text-color-of-textview-by-coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `getResources()` before you tell it what color you want.

```
getResources().getColor(color)
```

Answer (score 3):

`R.color.red` is a resource identifier (in Android they use `Integers`). You need to use that code like so:

```
Resources res = getResources();
int red = res.getColor(R.color.red);

Button b = new Button(this);
b.setTextColor(red);
b.setText("Some text");
```