# Give the text a color

Tags: android, textview

If I have something such as:

```
TextView description_label;
description_label.setText("Information");
```

How can I choose/set the colour of the text. Eg. have 'Information' in green

Comment: Try looking at the documentation for the object in question before you post here. Lots of times these simple questions can be answered there Ex. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: you may have a look at these threads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-text-color-of-textview-in-code and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

Answer (score 3):

Call `description.setTextColor()`.  Or use `android:textColor` in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView description_label;
description_label.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
description_label.setText("Information");
```