# Change the text Color based on value

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TextView in my application. Based on the value I get from server, I want to set the text color of the TextView.

This is my textview

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/approval_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="W" />
```

- if P I have to set Orange
- if A I have to set green
- if R I have to set red

How I can do this?

Comment: We're gonna need to see how you receive your values from the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-text-color-of-textview-in-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are getting vaule from server then first set that value in TextView as per ur requirenment..

```
Textview t = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.approval_status);
t.setText(value);


if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("P")
 t.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));
else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("A")
 t.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("R")
 t.setTextColor(Color.RED);
else
```

Answer (score 2):

Parse the response

```
public enum Status { PENDING, APPROVED, REJECTED }

public static Status statusFromResponse(String response) {
    if (response == "P") {
        return PENDING;
    } else if (response == "A") {
        return APPROVED;
    } else {
        return REJECTED;
    }
}
```

Retrive the TextView through

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.approval_status);
```

Then choose the color

```
switch (valueFromServer) {
     case PENDING:
         tv.setTextColor(0xff9900); //CHOOSE YOUR ORANGE
         break;
     case APPROVED:
         tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
         break;
     case REJECTED:
         tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
         break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(P)
{
textview.setTextColor(0xffCC00);// hex code of orange as 'Color' dont have orange color in list
}
else if(A)
{
textview.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
}
else if(R)
{
textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Textview approval_status = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.approval_status)

if(serverValue.equals("P")
    approval_status.setTextColor(0xFF6600); // Orange 
else if(serverValue.equals("A")
    approval_status.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
else if(serverValue.equals("R")
    approval_status.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code fragement where you get the answer from the server try this:

```
if(insertConditionForOrangeHere)
    myTextView.setTextColor(Color.ORANGE);
else if(insertConditionForGreenHere)
    myTextView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
else if(insertConditionForRedHere)
    myTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Textview tv = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.approval_status)

if(serverValue.equals("P")
    tv.setTextColor(0xFF6600); // Orange 
else if(serverValue.equals("A")
    tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
else if(serverValue.equals("R")
    tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
else
    // Handle it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Textview status = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.status)

if(value.equals("P")
    approval_status.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffae00")); // Orange Color Code
else if(value.equals("A")
    approval_status.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
else if(value.equals("R")
    approval_status.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```