# setTextColor in onpostexecute() from another xml (R.layout.list_item) Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to change the color of the text depending on the value from php jsonobject. The program can already get the value and able to display it on each textview. But my problem is, how can I change the color of each text view at the same time, depending on the Flimitstat, Vlimitstat and Climitstat. Hope you can help me!

This is my ThirdFragment.java

```
    package com.example.RadarOperationMonitoringSystem;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class ThirdFragment extends ListFragment {

    String site1 = "";
    String freq1 = "";
    String curr1 = "";
    String volts1 = "";
    String fstat1 = "";
    String vstat1 = "";
    String cstat1 = "";

    String site2 = "";
    String freq2 = "";
    String curr2 = "";
    String volts2 = "";
    String fstat2 = "";
    String vstat2 = "";
    String cstat2 = "";

    String site3 = "";
    String freq3 = "";
    String curr3 = "";
    String volts3 = "";
    String fstat3 = "";
    String vstat3 = "";
    String cstat3 = "";

    String site4 = "";
    String freq4 = "";
    String curr4 = "";
    String volts4 = "";
    String fstat4 = "";
    String vstat4 = "";
    String cstat4 = "";

    String site5 = "";
    String freq5 = "";
    String curr5 = "";
    String volts5 = "";
    String fstat5 = "";
    String vstat5 = "";
    String cstat5 = "";

    String site6 = "";
    String freq6 = "";
    String curr6 = "";
    String volts6 = "";
    String fstat6 = "";
    String vstat6 = "";
    String cstat6 = "";

    String site7 = "";
    String freq7 = "";
    String curr7 = "";
    String volts7 = "";
    String fstat7 = "";
    String vstat7 = "";
    String cstat7 = "";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    TextView freqa;
    TextView voltsa;
    TextView curra;
    TextView freqb;
    TextView voltsb;
    TextView currb;
    TextView freqc;
    TextView voltsc;
    TextView currc;
    TextView freqd;
    TextView voltsd;
    TextView currd;
    TextView freqe;
    TextView voltse;
    TextView curre;
    TextView freqf;
    TextView voltsf;
    TextView currf;
    TextView freqg;
    TextView voltsg;
    TextView currg;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.third_frag, container, false);

        freqa = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.frequency1);
        voltsa = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.acvoltage1);
        curra = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.accurrent1);
        freqb = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.frequency2);
        voltsb = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.acvoltage2);
        currb = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.accurrent2);
        freqc = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.frequency3);
        voltsc = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.acvoltage3);
        currc = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.accurrent3);
        freqd = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.frequency4);
        voltsd = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.acvoltage4);
        currd = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.accurrent4);
        freqe = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.frequency5);
        voltse = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.acvoltage5);
        curre = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.accurrent5);
        freqf = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.frequency6);
        voltsf = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.acvoltage6);
        currf = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.accurrent6);
        freqg = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.frequency7);
        voltsg = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.acvoltage7);
        currg = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.accurrent7);

        new GetContacts().execute();
        return v;
    }


    public class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // URL to get contacts JSON
        private static final String url = "http://10.0.2.2/radaroperations/energyreadings.php";

        private static final String TAG_SITENAME1 = "siteName1";
        private static final String TAG_FREQUENCY1 = "Frequency1";
        private static final String TAG_ACCURRENT1 = "AC_Voltage1";
        private static final String TAG_ACVOLTAGE1 = "AC_Current1";
        private static final String TAG_FSTAT1 = "Flimitstat1";
        private static final String TAG_VSTAT1 = "Vlimitstat1";
        private static final String TAG_CSTAT1 = "Climitstat1";

        private static final String TAG_SITENAME2 = "siteName2";
        private static final String TAG_FREQUENCY2 = "Frequency2";
        private static final String TAG_ACCURRENT2 = "AC_Voltage2";
        private static final String TAG_ACVOLTAGE2 = "AC_Current2";
        private static final String TAG_FSTAT2 = "Flimitstat2";
        private static final String TAG_VSTAT2 = "Vlimitstat2";
        private static final String TAG_CSTAT2 = "Climitstat2";

        private static final String TAG_SITENAME3 = "siteName3";
        private static final String TAG_FREQUENCY3 = "Frequency3";
        private static final String TAG_ACCURRENT3 = "AC_Voltage3";
        private static final String TAG_ACVOLTAGE3 = "AC_Current3";
        private static final String TAG_FSTAT3 = "Flimitstat3";
        private static final String TAG_VSTAT3 = "Vlimitstat3";
        private static final String TAG_CSTAT3 = "Climitstat3";

        private static final String TAG_SITENAME4 = "siteName4";
        private static final String TAG_FREQUENCY4 = "Frequency4";
        private static final String TAG_ACCURRENT4 = "AC_Voltage4";
        private static final String TAG_ACVOLTAGE4 = "AC_Current4";
        private static final String TAG_FSTAT4 = "Flimitstat4";
        private static final String TAG_VSTAT4 = "Vlimitstat4";
        private static final String TAG_CSTAT4 = "Climitstat4";

        private static final String TAG_SITENAME5 = "siteName5";
        private static final String TAG_FREQUENCY5 = "Frequency5";
        private static final String TAG_ACCURRENT5 = "AC_Voltage5";
        private static final String TAG_ACVOLTAGE5 = "AC_Current5";
        private static final String TAG_FSTAT5 = "Flimitstat5";
        private static final String TAG_VSTAT5 = "Vlimitstat5";
        private static final String TAG_CSTAT5 = "Climitstat5";

        private static final String TAG_SITENAME6 = "siteName6";
        private static final String TAG_FREQUENCY6 = "Frequency6";
        private static final String TAG_ACCURRENT6 = "AC_Voltage6";
        private static final String TAG_ACVOLTAGE6 = "AC_Current6";
        private static final String TAG_FSTAT6 = "Flimitstat6";
        private static final String TAG_VSTAT6 = "Vlimitstat6";
        private static final String TAG_CSTAT6 = "Climitstat6";

        private static final String TAG_SITENAME7 = "siteName7";
        private static final String TAG_FREQUENCY7 = "Frequency7";
        private static final String TAG_ACCURRENT7 = "AC_Voltage7";
        private static final String TAG_ACVOLTAGE7 = "AC_Current7";
        private static final String TAG_FSTAT7 = "Flimitstat7";
        private static final String TAG_VSTAT7 = "Vlimitstat7";
        private static final String TAG_CSTAT7 = "Climitstat7";

        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONObject c = null;




        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject c = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    site1 = c.getString(TAG_SITENAME1);
                    freq1 = c.getString(TAG_FREQUENCY1);
                    curr1 = c.getString(TAG_ACCURRENT1);
                    volts1 = c.getString(TAG_ACVOLTAGE1);
                    fstat1 = c.getString(TAG_FSTAT1);
                    vstat1 = c.getString(TAG_VSTAT1);
                    cstat1 = c.getString(TAG_CSTAT1);

                    site2 = c.getString(TAG_SITENAME2);
                    freq2 = c.getString(TAG_FREQUENCY2);
                    curr2 = c.getString(TAG_ACCURRENT2);
                    volts2 = c.getString(TAG_ACVOLTAGE2);
                    fstat2 = c.getString(TAG_FSTAT2);
                    vstat2 = c.getString(TAG_VSTAT2);
                    cstat2 = c.getString(TAG_CSTAT2);

                    site3 = c.getString(TAG_SITENAME3);
                    freq3 = c.getString(TAG_FREQUENCY3);
                    curr3 = c.getString(TAG_ACCURRENT3);
                    volts3 = c.getString(TAG_ACVOLTAGE3);
                    fstat3 = c.getString(TAG_FSTAT3);
                    vstat3 = c.getString(TAG_VSTAT3);
                    cstat3 = c.getString(TAG_CSTAT3);

                    site4 = c.getString(TAG_SITENAME4);
                    freq4 = c.getString(TAG_FREQUENCY4);
                    curr4 = c.getString(TAG_ACCURRENT4);
                    volts4 = c.getString(TAG_ACVOLTAGE4);
                    fstat4 = c.getString(TAG_FSTAT4);
                    vstat4 = c.getString(TAG_VSTAT4);
                    cstat4 = c.getString(TAG_CSTAT4);

                    site5 = c.getString(TAG_SITENAME5);
                    freq5 = c.getString(TAG_FREQUENCY5);
                    curr5 = c.getString(TAG_ACCURRENT5);
                    volts5 = c.getString(TAG_ACVOLTAGE5);
                    fstat5 = c.getString(TAG_FSTAT5);
                    vstat5 = c.getString(TAG_VSTAT5);
                    cstat5 = c.getString(TAG_CSTAT5);

                    site6 = c.getString(TAG_SITENAME6);
                    freq6 = c.getString(TAG_FREQUENCY6);
                    curr6 = c.getString(TAG_ACCURRENT6);
                    volts6 = c.getString(TAG_ACVOLTAGE6);
                    fstat6 = c.getString(TAG_FSTAT6);
                    vstat6 = c.getString(TAG_VSTAT6);
                    cstat6 = c.getString(TAG_CSTAT6);

                    site7 = c.getString(TAG_SITENAME7);
                    freq7 = c.getString(TAG_FREQUENCY7);
                    curr7 = c.getString(TAG_ACCURRENT7);
                    volts7 = c.getString(TAG_ACVOLTAGE7);
                    fstat7 = c.getString(TAG_FSTAT7);
                    vstat7 = c.getString(TAG_VSTAT7);
                    cstat7 = c.getString(TAG_CSTAT7);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_SITENAME1, site1);
                    contact.put(TAG_FREQUENCY1, freq1);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACCURRENT1, curr1);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACVOLTAGE1, volts1);
                    contact.put(TAG_FSTAT1, fstat1);
                    contact.put(TAG_VSTAT1, vstat1);
                    contact.put(TAG_CSTAT1, cstat1);

                    contact.put(TAG_SITENAME2, site2);
                    contact.put(TAG_FREQUENCY2, freq2);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACCURRENT2, curr2);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACVOLTAGE2, volts2);
                    contact.put(TAG_FSTAT2, fstat2);
                    contact.put(TAG_VSTAT2, vstat2);
                    contact.put(TAG_CSTAT2, cstat2);

                    contact.put(TAG_SITENAME3, site3);
                    contact.put(TAG_FREQUENCY3, freq3);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACCURRENT3, curr3);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACVOLTAGE3, volts3);
                    contact.put(TAG_FSTAT3, fstat3);
                    contact.put(TAG_VSTAT3, vstat3);
                    contact.put(TAG_CSTAT3, cstat3);

                    contact.put(TAG_SITENAME4, site4);
                    contact.put(TAG_FREQUENCY4, freq4);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACCURRENT4, curr4);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACVOLTAGE4, volts4);
                    contact.put(TAG_FSTAT4, fstat4);
                    contact.put(TAG_VSTAT4, vstat4);
                    contact.put(TAG_CSTAT4, cstat4);

                    contact.put(TAG_SITENAME5, site5);
                    contact.put(TAG_FREQUENCY5, freq5);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACCURRENT5, curr5);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACVOLTAGE5, volts5);
                    contact.put(TAG_FSTAT5, fstat5);
                    contact.put(TAG_VSTAT5, vstat5);
                    contact.put(TAG_CSTAT5, cstat5);

                    contact.put(TAG_SITENAME6, site6);
                    contact.put(TAG_FREQUENCY6, freq6);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACCURRENT6, curr6);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACVOLTAGE6, volts6);
                    contact.put(TAG_FSTAT6, fstat6);
                    contact.put(TAG_VSTAT6, vstat6);
                    contact.put(TAG_CSTAT6, cstat6);

                    contact.put(TAG_SITENAME7, site7);
                    contact.put(TAG_FREQUENCY7, freq7);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACCURRENT7, curr7);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACVOLTAGE7, volts7);
                    contact.put(TAG_FSTAT7, fstat7);
                    contact.put(TAG_VSTAT7, vstat7);
                    contact.put(TAG_CSTAT7, cstat7);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.clear();
                    contactList.add(contact);



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             *
             */

            //RADAR 1
            //Frequency 1 status
            if (TAG_FSTAT1.equals("1")){
                freqa.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else if(TAG_FSTAT1.equals("2")){
                freqa.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            //AC_Voltage 1 status
            if (TAG_VSTAT1.equals("1")){
                voltsa.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_VSTAT1.equals("2")){
                voltsa.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            //AC_Current 1 status
            if (TAG_CSTAT1.equals("1")){
                curra.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_CSTAT1.equals("2")){
                curra.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }

            //RADAR 2
            //Frequency 2 status
            if (TAG_FSTAT2.equals("1")){
                freqb.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_FSTAT2.equals("2")){
                freqb.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            //AC_Voltage 2 status
            if (TAG_VSTAT2.equals("1")){
                voltsb.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_VSTAT2.equals("2")){
                voltsb.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            //AC_Current 2 status
            if (TAG_CSTAT2.equals("1")){
                currb.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_CSTAT2.equals("2")){
                currb.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }

            //RADAR 3
            //Frequency 3 status
            if (TAG_FSTAT3.equals("1")){
                freqc.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_FSTAT3.equals("2")){
                freqc.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            //AC_Voltage 3 status
            if (TAG_VSTAT3.equals("1")){
                voltsc.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_VSTAT3.equals("2")){
                voltsc.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            //AC_Current 3 status
            if (TAG_CSTAT3.equals("1")){
                currc.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_CSTAT3.equals("2")){
                currc.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }

            //RADAR 4
            //Frequency 4 status
            if (TAG_FSTAT4.equals("1")){
                freqd.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_FSTAT4.equals("2")){
                freqd.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            //AC_Voltage 4 status
            if (TAG_VSTAT4.equals("1")){
                voltsd.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_VSTAT4.equals("2")){
                voltsd.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            //AC_Current 4 status
            if (TAG_CSTAT4.equals("1")){
                currd.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_CSTAT4.equals("2")){
                currd.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }

            //RADAR 5
            //Frequency 5 status
            if (TAG_FSTAT5.equals("1")){
                freqe.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_FSTAT5.equals("2")){
                freqe.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            //AC_Voltage 5 status
            if (TAG_VSTAT5.equals("1")){
                voltse.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_VSTAT5.equals("2")){
                voltse.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            //AC_Current 5 status
            if (TAG_CSTAT5.equals("1")){
                curre.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_CSTAT5.equals("2")){
                curre.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }

            //RADAR 6
            //Frequency 6 status
            if (TAG_FSTAT6.equals("1")){
                freqf.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_FSTAT6.equals("2")){
                freqf.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            //AC_Voltage 6 status
            if (TAG_VSTAT6.equals("1")){
                voltsf.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_VSTAT6.equals("2")){
                voltsf.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            //AC_Current 6 status
            if (TAG_CSTAT6.equals("1")){
                currf.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_CSTAT6.equals("2")){
                currf.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }

            //RADAR 7
            //Frequency 7 status
            if (TAG_FSTAT7.equals("1")){
                freqg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_FSTAT7.equals("2")){
                freqg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            //AC_Voltage 7 status
            if (TAG_VSTAT7.equals("1")){
                voltsg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_VSTAT7.equals("2")){
                voltsg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            //AC_Current 7 status
            if (TAG_CSTAT7.equals("1")){
                currg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
            else if(TAG_CSTAT7.equals("2")){
                currg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_SITENAME1, TAG_FREQUENCY1, TAG_ACCURRENT1,
                    TAG_ACVOLTAGE1,TAG_SITENAME2, TAG_FREQUENCY2, TAG_ACCURRENT2,
                    TAG_ACVOLTAGE2,TAG_SITENAME3, TAG_FREQUENCY3, TAG_ACCURRENT3,
                    TAG_ACVOLTAGE3, TAG_SITENAME4, TAG_FREQUENCY4, TAG_ACCURRENT4,
                    TAG_ACVOLTAGE4, TAG_SITENAME5, TAG_FREQUENCY5, TAG_ACCURRENT5,
                    TAG_ACVOLTAGE5, TAG_SITENAME6, TAG_FREQUENCY6, TAG_ACCURRENT6,
                    TAG_ACVOLTAGE6, TAG_SITENAME7, TAG_FREQUENCY7, TAG_ACCURRENT7,
                    TAG_ACVOLTAGE7},
                    new int[] { R.id.sitename1, R.id.frequency1,
                            R.id.accurrent1, R.id.acvoltage1, R.id.sitename2, R.id.frequency2,
                            R.id.accurrent2, R.id.acvoltage2, R.id.sitename3, R.id.frequency3,
                            R.id.accurrent3, R.id.acvoltage3, R.id.sitename4, R.id.frequency4,
                            R.id.accurrent4, R.id.acvoltage4, R.id.sitename5, R.id.frequency5,
                            R.id.accurrent5, R.id.acvoltage5, R.id.sitename6, R.id.frequency6,
                            R.id.accurrent6, R.id.acvoltage6, R.id.sitename7, R.id.frequency7,
                            R.id.accurrent7, R.id.acvoltage7});
            // updating listviews
            setListAdapter(adapter);



        }
    }

    public static ThirdFragment newInstance(String text) {

    ThirdFragment f = new ThirdFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}
}
```

Comment: You may need to make your custom Adapter instead of using `SimpleAdapter` for your `ListAdapter adapter` (last part of `onPostExecute`)

Answer (score 0):

You can check my listadapter and i have implemented the same concept to set the text color in two ways

```
 private class CustomerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RouteTrackerUser>
{
    Context context;
    int textViewResourceId;
    private ArrayList<RouteTrackerUser> originalitems;
    public CustomerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<RouteTrackerUser> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.originalitems = items;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                v = inflater.inflate(textViewResourceId, parent, false);
            }
            final RouteTrackerUser r = originalitems.get(position);
            if (r != null) {
                    TextView textName= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sname);
                    TextView postal=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.postal);
                    if(r.getVisited().equals("true"))
                    {
                    if(textName != null)
                    {
                        textName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightpurple));
                        textName.setText(r.getStorename());
                    }
                    if(postal != null)
                    {
                        postal.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightpurple));
                        postal.setText("Address: "+r.getPostalcode());
                    }
                    }
                    if(r.getVisited().equals("false"))
                    {
                        if(textName != null)
                        {
                            textName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkpurple));
                            textName.setText(r.getStorename());
                        }
                        if(postal != null)
                        {
                            postal.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkpurple));
                            postal.setText("Address: "+r.getPostalcode());
                        }   
                    }
                    if(RouteTrackerApp.sharedPreference.getInt(RouteTrackerApp.SHARED_ACCESS_UTYPE, 0) == Constants.VAR_TYPE_SALES_PERSON){
                        v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            viewdata(r.getUsername(),r.getStoreid(),r.getAccountid(),r.getUid(),r.getVisitplanid(),r.getVisited(),r.getStorename());
                        }});
                    }
            }
            return v;
    }
  }
```

and on PostExecute i  called this adapter like

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<RouteTrackerUser> result) 
{
    if(result!=null)
    {
//  System.out.println("User with result===>"+result);
    /*for(RouteTrackerUser r :result ){
        System.out.println("StoreName===>"+r.getStorename());}*/
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        TextView username=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.usrname);
        final String sname=intent.getExtras().getString("user_name");
        username.setText("Welcome, "+sname);
        TextView todayvisits=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.todaylist);
        todayvisits.setText("TODAY'S STORE VISITS");
        userAdapter = new CustomerAdapter(ViewYourPlanList.this, R.layout.view_your_plan_list,result);
        userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        userList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        userList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        dialog.dismiss();
        }
```

else
if you are want to implement in listfragment ! Design a customadapter and set the text color like i shown below and call this customadapter on postexecute.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void setData(List<Model> data) {
    clear();
    if (data != null) {
        for (Model appEntry : data) {
            System.out.println("cust adptr set data: "+appEntry.getStorename());
            add(appEntry);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Populate new items in the list.
 */
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_your_plan_weekly, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    Model item = getItem(position);
    int dayVal = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1;
    ImageView arrow=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.arrow_image);
    arrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if(item.getTabId().equals(String.valueOf(dayVal))){
         arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if(item.getVisited().equals("true"))
    {
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sname)).setText(item.getStorename());
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.postal)).setText(item.getPostal());
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sname)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D397D4"));
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.postal)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D397D4"));
    }
    if(item.getVisited().equals("false"))
    {
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sname)).setText(item.getStorename());
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.postal)).setText(item.getPostal());
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sname)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9B419B"));
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.postal)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9B419B"));
    }
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: my solution is useful or just ask what you need after trying this >?

Comment: looks like this is not what I want, because I just want to change the text color of particular Text view depending on the value the app got from the database.

Comment: actually I'm sorry but i didn't understand your code. well I'm a newbie. :/ Hope you can still help me.

Comment: Okay so have you tried all the solutions...just follow the link below and try these five ways which suits you best....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-text-color-of-textview-in-code

Comment: you can try the answer of 
Nanne in the above link

Comment: sorry but I don't get it. I tried all the codes above, but the errors for me are so primitive. would you edit the code itself?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(), contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_SITENAME1, TAG_FREQUENCY1, TAG_ACCURRENT1,
                TAG_ACVOLTAGE1,TAG_SITENAME2, TAG_FREQUENCY2, TAG_ACCURRENT2,
                TAG_ACVOLTAGE2,TAG_SITENAME3, TAG_FREQUENCY3, TAG_ACCURRENT3,
                TAG_ACVOLTAGE3, TAG_SITENAME4, TAG_FREQUENCY4, TAG_ACCURRENT4,
                TAG_ACVOLTAGE4, TAG_SITENAME5, TAG_FREQUENCY5, TAG_ACCURRENT5,
                TAG_ACVOLTAGE5, TAG_SITENAME6, TAG_FREQUENCY6, TAG_ACCURRENT6,
                TAG_ACVOLTAGE6, TAG_SITENAME7, TAG_FREQUENCY7, TAG_ACCURRENT7,
                TAG_ACVOLTAGE7},
                new int[] { R.id.sitename1, R.id.frequency1,
                        R.id.accurrent1, R.id.acvoltage1, R.id.sitename2, R.id.frequency2,
                        R.id.accurrent2, R.id.acvoltage2, R.id.sitename3, R.id.frequency3,
                        R.id.accurrent3, R.id.acvoltage3, R.id.sitename4, R.id.frequency4,
                        R.id.accurrent4, R.id.acvoltage4, R.id.sitename5, R.id.frequency5,
                        R.id.accurrent5, R.id.acvoltage5, R.id.sitename6, R.id.frequency6,
                        R.id.accurrent6, R.id.acvoltage6, R.id.sitename7, R.id.frequency7,
                        R.id.accurrent7, R.id.acvoltage7});
        // updating listviews
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

and instead of SimpleAdapter you use customadapter. In CustomAdapter you can set the textcolor as i shown in my previous post.Just go through the class "public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter "

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I found already the answer to my question: by putting view getview function on simpleadapter. Anyway, THANK YOU for giving ideas and tips. :)