# Different textColor for TextView with custom theme

Tags: java, android

I want to create a custom theme for my application, but I have a small problem. In my TextViews I use different textColors so for my custom theme i put

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/myColor</item>
```

The problem is: How can I set different textColors for different TextViews? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't define it in theme then, create a style and apply it to different textviews.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [TextView#setTextColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(int)%20%22%22):

```
text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(250,20,250));
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-the-text-color-of-textview-in-code%20%22%22) are some examples where you can also get the text color from resources:

```
text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor));
```

If you absolutely want to use Theme/Styles you can set a custom style for each `TextView`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Sample Text"
        style="@style/my_style" />
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) is a good explanation about creating styles!