# How to use attributes to change text color from activity

Tags: android, textview, attr

This is my code

```
 TextView text_language_name4 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text);
                     if (text_language_name4 != null) {
                         int text_color4 = selected
                                 ? getResources().getColor(R.color.readcolor)
                                         : getResources().getColor(R.color.readcolor);                
                                 text_language_name4.setTextColor(text_color4);
                         text_language_name4.setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true);

                 }
```

When i am using R.attr.mytheme my app forces close

Any suggestions for using attr to change color of a text view

Comment: Please clean your project first.

Comment: already has answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7443169/3879470

Comment: That answer is different than asked. Color needs to be changed by using attribute rather than color resource

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the theme color try like this:

```
TypedValue tV = new TypedValue();
Theme theme = context.getTheme();
boolean success = theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.theme_color, tV, true);
int colorFromTheme;
if(success)
    colorFromTheme = tV.data;
else
    // value not found....
```

Now set,

```
textView.setTextColor(colorFromTheme);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this if i understood your problem right:

> textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

While "#ffffff" is the hex value of the color.

Answer (score -1):

**Assuming you have:**

```
<color name="green">#0000ff00</color>
```

**And here is code:**

```
int greenColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.green);
 String strGreenColor = "#"+Integer.toHexString(greenColor);

mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(""+greenColor));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but i want to get colors from my theme and when i am doing such thing my app forces close getResources().getColor(R.attr.mytheme)                                         : getResources().getColor(R.attr.mytheme);

Comment: whats the error that force closes the app? the above ans is correct, you can use it...

Comment: this is not what i am asking , i am asking if i can use attr for example getResources().getColor(R.attr.green); I have 2 themes in my app and both have different color .