# Android ARGB setTextColor not working

Tags: java, android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    int numAlpha = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.alphaInteger));
    int numRed = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.redInteger));
    int numGreen = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.greenInteger));
    int numBlue = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.blueInteger));
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(message);
    setContentView(textView);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.argb(numAlpha, numRed, numGreen, numBlue));
}
```

I have an app where user can set ARGB and then TextView should be set to what user has defined. However, the text doesn't show up at all. When I remove the textView.setTextColor line, it starts showing again. I tested numAlpha, numRed, numGreen and numBlue with Log.v and they output everything correctly. 
What's the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure message isn't empty? What are the values for a/r/g/b?

Comment: Message is not empty, as I already wrote, it works just fine if I remove textView.setTextColor line. There's a lot of code which set it but are you sure you need it? I already tested them with Log.v and they are correct.

Comment: no I don't need it.  What are the values of a r g b ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-the-text-color-of-textview-in-code

Comment: I found out that all values are set depending on what I wrote in Blue field. Maybe something is wrong with this:         intent.putExtra(alphaInteger, Integer.toString(text_alpha));
        intent.putExtra(redInteger, Integer.toString(text_red));
        intent.putExtra(greenInteger, Integer.toString(text_green));
        intent.putExtra(blueInteger, Integer.toString(text_blue));

Answer (score 0):

What's your numAlpha? It can't be zero or to small, and the a,r,g,b range is 0-255. Try to use:

```
public static int rgb(int red, int green, int blue);
```