# ClassCastException on TextView setColor method in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set the color of a view which is stored in sharedpreference. But when I try to parse the color string, it throws ClassCastException.

Here is my code.

```
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String textColor = sharedPref.getString("textColor", "#00ff00");
        String backgroundColor = sharedPref.getString("backgroundColor", "#000000");
        digitalClock.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(textColor));
```

According to other [stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-the-text-color-of-textview-in-code), I have to parse the color string to Color integer using following code.

```
Color.parseColor(textColor)
```

But it doesn't output integer value.

Here is the logcat output.

```
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.co.andromedatech.digitalclock/uk.co.andromedatech.digitalclock.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:205)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at uk.co.andromedatech.digitalclock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992) 
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127) 
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158) 
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441) 
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
11-16 23:04:49.009 15566-15566/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-16 23:04:50.183 15566-15566/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15566 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Stack trace is saying that `textColor` pref is actually an int. You should check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:205)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at uk.co.andromedatech.digitalclock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
```

Your `getString()` call is what is failing, because `SharedPreferences` thinks that the preference is an integer, not a string. Either:

- You are storing the preference via `putInt()`, or
- The syntax of `#` followed by hex digits is being used by `SharedPreferences` for encoding integers, even though you may be setting the value via `putString()`

If you are storing the value via `putInt()`, either switch to `putString()` or `getInt()`.

If you are already storing the value via `putString()`, then my latter scenario is more likely, and you might consider just switching to `putInt()` and `getInt()`.

Comment: Well, I use PreferenceScreen to store that value. Following is the code,     <com.rarepebble.colorpicker.ColorPreference
        android:key="textColor"
        android:title="@string/pref_text_color"
        app:colorpicker_defaultColor="#00ff00"
        />

Comment: @Isuru: If [this is the source code](https://github.com/martin-stone/hsv-alpha-color-picker-android/blob/master/colorpicker/src/main/java/com/rarepebble/colorpicker/ColorPreference.java) to what you are using, it is saving the preference as an integer. Change your code to use `getInt()` instead of `getString()`.

Comment: @MikeM.: Yes, thanks, though as it turns out from the earlier comments, that doesn't appear to be the case anyway.

Comment: Thanks! @CommonsWare. That was the problem. Anyway your book is the best. Learned lot from it.