# How to change color of some of the items in listview by default android?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, listitem

I have a `ListView` that consists of booked appointments and unbooked appointments,I can change the color when its clicked but i want to know how to change the color of booked by default.

When the data is fetched and shown in listview the booked and unbooked should be displayed in different colors.Is it possible?

Can anyone help me out please?
Thanks in advance!
Just a guidance is enough!

Comment: yes it is possible. You r checking a condition right to differentiate booked and unbooked. In the adapter set back ground color of that item programatically if its booked.

Comment: Are you using textviews inside your listview to display booked and unbooked appoinments ? If yes, then its simple to change the color of Textviews.

Comment: Put your arraylist flag for booked &  unbooked accroding to that you can set color to listItem LinearLayout & set color in getView method.

Comment: post your adapter file & inflated xml.

Comment: Ya i am setting textview for it! Any tutorials for it guys?

Comment: @SharathKumar Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-the-text-color-of-textview-in-code

Comment: I am using parse db.so i am shifting it to own hosting now.Adapter and xml  are not yet ready! can you give me links for those tutorials pls?

Comment: Actually both booked and unbooked will be in same listview sorted based on timings

Comment: @SharathKumar how you got those data from webservice or local database

Comment: From web service @Kaushik

Comment: is there any flag for recognizing already bookmarked or not. If not then tell the dev who develop backend service to put one flag and in adapter set text color or background color whatever using that flag value.

Comment: No actually booked and unbooked will be saved in two different tables.I retrieved and displayed it in listview.

Answer (score 3):

You should follow the steps as follow.

1. You first need 1 column in your database where you can check the status of appointment i.e. booked or unbooked [boolean field is expected]  or Can use ENUM if more than two types of status with varchar column.
2. After that you need to get data form database to array adaptor.

   ```
         Class MyAdaptor extends ArrayAdaptor<YourEntityClass>{
          ...............
         }
   ```
3. After that you need to override the getView method inside array adaptor class  if you are using custom adaptor.

   ```
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Your_TextView_File, parent, false);
      ........
      return rowView;
     }
   ```
4. Now inside getView check if the if(object.getAppoinmentStatus == true) show some changes else show some changes.

   ```
       final YourEntityClass a = getItem(position);
       if(a.getAppoinmentStatus == true){
            //Change required text color
       }else{
          //Default
       }
   ```
5. Get On item Click listener in class

   ```
    public class ListActivity extends Activity{
         private MyAdaptor adaptor;
         private ListView lv;
        @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.YourActivityLayout);
       adaptor = new MyAdaptor(this);
       lv = (ListView)findById(R.id.YourListView);
       onItemClickListener();
       }

   public void onItemClickListener(){
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
           if (adaptor.getItem(i).getAppoinmentStatus() == 0){
                //Do Some Work
             }else{
                 //Do some Work
                }
           }
    }
   ```

   This might help you

Comment: Ok i done it.Now how to give onClick for only items which are in not booked?

Comment: Create the adaptor object in your activity class for which this adaptor is used.

Comment: Ho thanks alot! will try it out and will get back to u

Comment: This is how you can achieve required...  Ask more if any doubt

Answer (score 0):

You can check the data type in your `Adapter` class before displaying.Set a bit for booked and unbooked data.Check the bit before setting data to `ListView` and change the color accordingly.See the below code snippet.
Here, `status` is the bit whose value you can pass through the constructor.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);  
if (status == 1) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);  
} else {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);  
}

return view;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your getView() of Adapter method try something like this,

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final ListContent holder;
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_item, parent, false);
                holder = new ListContent();

                holder.line_main = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.line_main);
                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ListContent) v.getTag();
            }

            Model pi = arrayModelList.get(position);

            if (pi.getFlag() == 1) {
                holder.line_main.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(YourActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            } else if (pi.getFlag() == 2) {
                holder.line_main.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(YourActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
            } else {
                holder.line_main.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(YourActivity.this, R.color.colorLightPrimary2));
            }
            return v;
        }
```

In your model Class generate getter and setter method for flag,

```
private int flag;//1 = boxed,2 = unboxed

public int getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(int flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
```