# Countdowntimer Last Seconds

Tags: android

I have a 45 seconds countdowntimer. And I want to set up my countdown timer to, Whether red lettering the last 10 seconds... So like a quiz game last 10 seconds means hurry up so it should be red color when last 10 seconds comes. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the color in the Text View (where the countdown timer is shown). please see [How to set the text color of TextView in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-the-text-color-of-textview-in-code)