# setTextColor depending on random String from array - Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, random

I have a String array with color names and an array with colors:

```
String[] words = new String[] {"yellow", "white", "green"};
int[] colors = new int[] {Color.YELLOW, Color.WHITE, Color.GREEN};
```

My `TextView` is set to one of these words randomly and now I want to set the text color to yellow if yellow was chosen, etc. I tried this with an `if` statement, but it keeps showing only black words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Retrieve the word that the TextView has:

```
String chosenWord = String.valueOf(yourTextView.getText());
```

2) Get the `chosenWord` position in `words`:

```
int position = Arrays.asList(words).indexOf(chosenWord);
```

3) Get the corresponding color:

```
int newColor = Color.BLACK;
if(position > -1) {
    newColor = colors[position];
}
yourTextView.setTextColor(newColor);
```

[For all the ways to change a TextView color check this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4602929/2819864)

---

BTW, do you know [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)? You can use them in this cases when you need to map a key with an specific value.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a model object for it. E.g.

```
 public class MyColor {
    public String mColorName;
    public int mColor;

    public MyColor (String name, int color) {
       mColorName = name;
       mColor = color;
    }
 }
```

and then declare your array like

```
 MyColor[] color = new MyColor[] { new MyColor("yellow", Color.YELLOW),  new MyColor("white", Color.WHITE), new MyColor("green", Color.GREEN) };
```

This way you can easily access the name associated to the color

Answer (score 0):

With this way you have one array and easier to manage.

```
public class MyColor {
    public String name;
    public int code;

    public MyColor(String n, int c) {
        this.name = n;
        this.code = c;
    }

}

ArrayList<MyColor> colors = new ArrayList<>();
colors.add(new MyColor("black", Color.BLACK));
colors.add(new MyColor("yellow", Color.YELLOW));
colors.add(new MyColor("green", Color.GREEN));

for (MyColor color : colors) {
    if(color.name.equals(colorStr)) {
        yourTextView.setTextColor(color.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if(tv.getTextColors().getDefaultColor() == colors[0])
    tv.setText(words[0]);
else if(tv.getTextColors().getDefaultColor() == colors[1])
    tv.setText(words[1]);
else if(tv.getTextColors().getDefaultColor() == colors[2])
    tv.setText(words[2]);
```