# How to set color in Java code (Android)

Tags: java, android

My code,

```
if (position == 1) {
    return new DummyItem(String.valueOf(position), "  ABOUT "+"ME", String.valueOf(position));
} else if (position == 2) {
    return new DummyItem(String.valueOf(position), "  ABOUT "+"Office", String.valueOf(position));
}
```

Here in first case return value is "ABOUT ME". So I want to set pink color to "ABOUT ME". How to set color in Java code?

ABOUT ME text field is works like clickable field and when I click on "ABOUT ME" it will call `aboutme.XML` (xml contain just text/data).

Comment: Where you are going to put the ABOUT ME/ ABOUT Office text in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

For which Object you would like to set a Color?
If you like to set the TextColor of an TextView you could try this:
[How to set the text color of TextView in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-the-text-color-of-textview-in-code?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying this out in android's text view.
use this as android M requires this.
`textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color));`