# Changing the color of only one world in a text view

Tags: android, textview

I am create an android app with android studio that retrieves text from mysqli database using volley library into a text view. I want to check if the text contains "@"  and if to does it it should be coloured red. That Is, I want only the "@" to be changed. Please guys how will I achieve that?

Comment: Please show some work. Do you have code to get the text and display without colours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will change the color of only one word in this case "@"

Esto cambiara el color de una sola letra, en este caso "@"

```
String newText = String.valueOf(text.getText()).replace("@","<font color='#fff0000'>@</font>");
        text.setText(Html.fromHtml(newText));
```

Comment: Don't forget to import the corresponding libraries.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your reply. A very special thanks  to you @LuisAguilar

Answer (score 0):

use an if statement like

```
if text.contains("@") {
text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

read here [How to set the text color of TextView in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-the-text-color-of-textview-in-code) to learn more about changing text color

Comment: I already did that but it changes all the texts in the text view.

Comment: I already did that but it changes all the texts in the text view.

Comment: you mean it changes the color for all the text views?