# How to change text color according to values of array?

Tags: android, arrays, string, colors, textview

I am writing an application for android. I have a database and there is too many word. These words go to the array for changing color of only one string in my activity.I thought that I can use easily span class.there is a problem in my code.Span class is using integer values but my values are string.I want to change color of my textview according to values of array when I click to my button.Only one color and If my string(metin_yazısı) has not word ,I don"t want to change it.  How can I use my array string in my textview.

```
//I get it all data from database.

     Cursor data = mDatabase.getData();
        while (data.moveToNext()){

            kelimeler_array.add(data.getString(1)) ;


        }


     kelimeleri_isaretle_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


try {

    SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(metin_yazısı);
    spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 3, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    user_textview.setText(metin_yazısı);


}catch (Exception e){

}

     }
        });
```

Comment: I want to like this. This is my array.(kelimeler_array).This is my text : Hello everybody ; I am developer. My array has "everybody" , "am". When I click the button.İf Array has words like in my text.My array"s words change ıts color.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-the-text-color-of-textview-in-code