# Android - how to set background color of all screens?

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the best practice to maintain styles of fonts and colors. I made a colors.xml file which I have used to change colors on seperate elements like buttons, but I am not sure how Android wants developers to organize their styles.

For example, I would like all screens to have the same background color. How do I do that? Is it something I need to specify for each Activity layout xml? Or elsewhere? How do I accomplish it?

Comment: you create [styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) and apply them to your UI elements

Comment: @zapl rigth its what I was doing. What I was wondering was how to apply a style to the entire screen.  Like a background color for every screen?

Comment: you can either apply some background theme to each topmost LinearLayout (or whatever you use) or you can do that via a [theme for your activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme)

Answer (score 219, accepted):

A quick and easy way to make sure every activity has the same background color, is to create a theme for your activities to use.  That theme would specify the android:windowBackground.

First define the color in values/colors.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="background">#FF0000 </color>
</resources>
```

Create a themes.xml file in res/values that references that color:

```
<resources>
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"> 
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

... and then in your AndroidManifest.xml specify this as the theme for your activities to use.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
```

Comment: I got an error when implementing this code in the themes.xml as it doesn't recognise the hex color code here:

    <item name="android:windowBackground">#FF0000</item>

Comment: just put the color hex in a @color resource, then reference it thus <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/my_background</item>

Comment: this is not the right answer. please correct your answer to match Chris's comment NPike

Comment: Edit the style in `styles.xml` instead.

Comment: windowBackground has no effect. I think this flag is only to set / change drawables not colors!

Answer (score 20):

Update your android studio to 1.4 it has inbuilt theme editor. as you can see in below image

[image]

Comment: how to open Theme Editir in android 2.1 preview version

Comment: open styles.xml file and you will see open in editor text at Top Right corner click on that.

Comment: But my case hide and problem solve it when restart android studio thank you show mach

Comment: To open it go to Tools -> Android -> Theme Editor.

Comment: The Editor is out of support. Since Android Studio 3.3 it is removed.

Answer (score 9):

You can also set the background at the application level in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
   ...
   android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

(Note: I cannot this as a comment of the accepted answer as my reputation is too low).