# Setting Android Theme background color

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm trying to modify the default background theme color, which should be easy but surprisingly I can't get it working. Please note that I want the change to be across the entire app, not just for a single activity. Here is my code:

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <color name="white_opaque">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="pitch_black">#FF000000</color>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@color/white_opaque</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white_opaque</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white_opaque</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

and of course in the manifest

```
<application
    .
    .
    .
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > 
</application>
```

Android doc which I consulted on modifying themes:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

I've tried switching between white_opaque and pitch_black for all the xml attributes but it doesn't change a thing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try removing the alpha channel

Comment: Alright I just did, still the same though.

Comment: This is the best solution I've read 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33213433/963543

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Okay turned out that I made a really silly mistake. The device I am using for testing is running Android 4.0.4, API level 15.

The styles.xml file that I was editing is in the default values folder. I edited the styles.xml in values-v14 folder and it works all fine now.

Comment: Or you can just delete the other styles folders if you are not using them. I had the same problem and fixed it with one styles.xml, in the 'values' folder. My problem was that I had a theme item for the Activity in the manifest file (which of course overrode the AppTheme).

Answer (score 58):

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 19):

Open `res -> values -> styles.xml` and to your `<style>` add this line replacing with your image path `<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>`. Example:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

There is a `<item name ="android:colorBackground">@color/black</item>` also, that will affect not only your main window background but all the component in your app. Read about customize theme [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#CustomizeTheme).

If you want [version specific styles](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#Versions):

> If a new version of Android adds theme attributes that you want to
>   use, you can add them to your theme while still being compatible with
>   old versions. All you need is another styles.xml file saved in a
>   values directory that includes the resource version qualifier. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> res/values/styles.xml        # themes for all versions
> res/values-v21/styles.xml    # themes for API level 21+ only
> ```
>
> Because the styles in the values/styles.xml file are available for all
>   versions, your themes in values-v21/styles.xml can inherit them. As
>   such, you can avoid duplicating styles by beginning with a "base"
>   theme and then extending it in your version-specific styles.

[Read more here(doc in theme)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes).