# Unfortunately project has stopped. Doesnt work donation inset. Why?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an application. So I've got an error on the donation inset. Probably smth is wrong with sms buttons. Though they work in other insets, so do links. Here is the code:

Donate.java

```
    package com.example.sadaka;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Donate extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle donate){
    super.onCreate(donate);
    setContentView(R.layout.donate);
    Button sms1,sms2,sms3,sms4,b1,b2,b3,b4;
    TextView t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6;
    ImageButton payment;
    payment=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.n);
    payment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Uri addr=Uri.parse("http://sadakafund.com/donate_phone.php");
            Intent myIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,addr);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    sms1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cont);
    sms2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.butt7);
    sms3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    sms4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.help);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.aboutapp);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.don);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.zkt);
    b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.View1);
    t3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.View2);
    t4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.View3);
    t5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.View4);
    t6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    sms1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SmsManager smsm=SmsManager.getDefault();
            String number="3116";
            smsm.sendTextMessage(number, null, "nasr 50", null, null);
        }
    });
    sms2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SmsManager smsm=SmsManager.getDefault();
            String number="3116";
            smsm.sendTextMessage(number, null, "nasr 100", null, null);
        }
    });
    sms3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SmsManager smsm=SmsManager.getDefault();
            String number="3116";
            smsm.sendTextMessage(number, null, "nasr 250", null, null);
        }   
    });
    sms4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SmsManager smsm=SmsManager.getDefault();
            String number="3116";
            smsm.sendTextMessage(number, null, "nasr 500", null, null);
        }
    });
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i1=new Intent(Donate.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i1=new Intent(Donate.this,Donate.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    });
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i1=new Intent(Donate.this,Zakat.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    });
    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i1=new Intent(Donate.this,Inf.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    });
}

}
```

donate.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/View1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Пожертвовать"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/butt7"
        android:text="500 Р"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/View2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/View4"
        android:text="Банковская карта"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butt7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cont"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="100 Р"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/aboutapp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Новости"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/View4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/aboutapp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Услуга доступна для жителей России"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zkt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/don"
        android:text="Закят"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/zkt"
        android:text="Информация"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/View3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/don"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="С помощью СМС*"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/View3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/View1"
        android:text="Банковская карта"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cont"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/View1"
        android:text="50 Р"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/View4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cont"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="250 Р"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/butt7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cont"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="Выберите сумму пожертвования"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/don"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/aboutapp"
        android:text="Пожертвовать"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/n"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/butt7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:src="@drawable/visa_mc" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sadaka"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <permission 
        android:name="com.example.sadaka.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.sadaka.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAZ4ntXyoqLud8mjORXQPuCUsQ9yTrLUD4"/>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.sadaka.MAINACTIVITY"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name=".Donate"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.sadaka.DONATE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".Zakat"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.sadaka.ZAKAT"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                 <activity
            android:name=".Inf"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.sadaka.INF"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                         <activity
            android:name=".Cont"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.sadaka.CONT"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>       
        <activity
            android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.sadaka.ABOUT"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>       
        <activity
            android:name=".Email"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.sadaka.EMAIL"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>       
        <activity
            android:name=".Sms"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.sadaka.SMS"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>       
            </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat:

```
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sadaka/com.example.sadaka.Donate}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at com.example.sadaka.Donate.onCreate(Donate.java:17)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     ... 11 more
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     ... 23 more
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f090000 a=-1 r=0x7f090000}
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2063)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3364)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3293)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:453)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:242)
04-29 01:35:35.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2319):     ... 26 more
```

Thanks for help

update:

styles.xml

```
 <resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: I don't see a question mark in this "question".

Comment: Please provide the logcat (errors list) with your questions. Your issues might be anything... It may help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The error may come from the fact that you are setting the background of your `RelativeLayout` to a `style` in `donate.xml`: `android:background="@style/AppBaseTheme"`

Change the background to use a `Drawable` or `Color` to fix your issue.

If you want to set the style of your `Activity`, check out the code in this question: [Setting Android Theme background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779679/setting-android-theme-background-color)

Comment: Still the same. I removed it like in other xml files but it doesnt work

Comment: Can you please paste your `styles.xml` or whatever file contains `AppBaseTheme`?

Comment: pasted to the end of question

Comment: Weird. So the issue is this last part of the stack trace: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f090000 a=-1 r=0x7f090000}` Somewhere it is attempting to assign a non-color/non-path drawable where a color/path drawable is expected. Are `@drawable/visa_mc` and `@drawable/icon` images?

Comment: yes. both are showable. but even if i remove those buttons the inset doesnt work