# How do I change colorBackground in custom theme Android?

Tags: android, background, themes

I wanna change backgroundColor in my entire application through themes. This is my effort, unsuccessful though:

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<color name="bgColor">#FFFFFF</color>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/bgColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/bgColor</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
 <application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

I've tried this on android 4.4 and 5.0. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Okay turned out that I made a really silly mistake. The device I am using for testing is running Android 4.0.4, API level 15.
The styles.xml file that I was editing is in the default values folder. I edited the styles.xml in values-v14 folder and it works all fine now.*

This is [Stark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/948781/stark)'s post where he pointed out a similar problem to yours and he has found a solution. You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11781005/3812244).

Comment: If that helped you, can you please mark this question as answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hey update you android studio to 1.4 it has inbuilt theme Editor as you can see in below picture.

[image]