# How do I add a background image to my app?

Tags: android, android-layout

**How to add an image and set it as my apps background**

I know that you paste your desired image into the drawable folder.Is it a problem within the code itself, or I supposed to create a RelativeLayout? Or is it simply just a line change within the code provided?

**Here is my code without altering any lines.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="anaheim.startercalculator.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/firstNumEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter a value"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/secondNumEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter a value"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstNumEditText"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addBtn"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:text="ADD"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/secondNumEditText"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="143dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/multBtn"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="MULTIPLY"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addBtn"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="263dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="143dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="48sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="139dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/multBtn"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/subBtn"
    android:layout_width="98dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="Subtract"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.027"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/multBtn"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="323dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="143dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/divBtn"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="DIVIDE"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subBtn"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="377dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Very simply, add to your ConstratintLayout: `android:background="@drawable/your_image"`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set background to the app then you can use `windowBackground` in your theme

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/sample_bg</item>
```

And you can give background to any view or View Group, In xml you can give like this android:background="[your background image or color]".

Using color - `android:background="@color/colorPrimary"`
Using drawable - `android:background="@drawable/sample_bg"`

If you want to give background for complete layout, then you can give background to your root layout(in your case `ConstraintLayout` layout is root)

Note :

> For buttons, you can give [color state list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html), and for ImageView you
>   can give Background and source image too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give background for complete layout, then go with this code :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    **android:background="@drawable/ic_add"**>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your xml;

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="anaheim.startercalculator.MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/login_0018_background"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <Write your code xml here>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please avoid adding unnecessary nested layouts and unnecessary Views. Nested layouts are bad for performances.

Answer (score 1):

Add a RelativeLayout to your root and put all the EditText s in it.
Then set your drawable to your RelativeLayout's background by using background property of the Relative layout.

Comment: Please avoid adding unnecessary nested layouts. Nested layouts are bad for performances.

Answer (score 1):

You tell your ImageView to constrain its top side to the top side of the button

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="mreram.testapp.MainActivity">
<ImageView
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="..."
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

<Write your code xml here>
```

Comment: You really don't need to add an extra ImageView to the existing layout.

Comment: @ModularSynth you can't scale image with background attribute !

Comment: Background images are automatically scaled to fit their container.

Comment: @ModularSynth 
set background the image to fill the View... It stretches the image and it does not look good this way

Comment: That's the way background images work. You may use other types of resources as well, i.e.: colors, gradients, 9 patches, ...

Comment: @ModularSynth yes background images just good for colors, gradients, 9 patches , shape drawable,...
not work good for photos...

Comment: Unless you don't want to use a very blurry image as a background.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it two ways.

First one is set the image as background of constraintlayout using

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_image"
```

or add an imageview as first element of constraintlayout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_image"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The second way is poor. You really don't need to add an extra ImageView to the existing layout.

Answer (score 1):

`android:background="@drawable/back"`

add above line in `ConstraintLayout` and remember `back` is my background image name

Answer (score 1):

android:src="@drawable/your_image"
android:scaleType = "centerCrop"

Answer (score 0):

Open `res -> values -> styles.xml` and to your `<style>` add this line replacing with your image path `<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>`. Example:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

There is a `<item name ="android:colorBackground">@color/black</item>` also, that will affect not only your main window background but all the component in your app.

[Read more here(doc in theme)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes).

If you want to add android version specific style, [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779679/setting-android-theme-background-color/59655590#59655590) or use above link.