# How can I add background image in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

so this is my first question in StackOverflow. Actually I want a set a beautiful background photo in recyclerView.So how can I add?
help me
I am attaching some photo

Comment: Please add the code you have written so far.

Comment: Please share a sample Image that how it should be, or share your code what you have tried

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a background image to my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518639/how-do-i-add-a-background-image-to-my-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need to add an image to your project. Go to the `res` -> `drawable` directory and add your desired image there.

Then go into the layout xml file that contains your recyclerview and simply set the background attribute  `android:background="@drawable/myBackground"`