# How to set global application background color?

Tags: android, android-theme

I know that I can assign background color to individual views in `layout.xml` files. The bg color of a root layout of, say, `Activity` is effectively the background color of this activity. But is there a way to set this color globally to the whole application so that all activities and fragments get it automatically? I'm using the `Theme.AppCompat` theme.

Or am I not supposed to alter the default grey color at all?

Comment: check it <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156816/android-how-to-set-background-color-of-all-screens>

Comment: The previous answer is not completely correct for a particular case, when you animate window transition (enter or exit), especially if you use scale animation (scale down (< 1.0) for x and/or y). Each activity is actually a window. So if there is no activity below the animated one, you'll see black borders while your activity will be scaled up to 1.0. I did not find a way to set application (not activity of window) background color globally, do you?

Comment: @MykolaMelnyk: I have come across this problem, but thank you very much for describing it and even giving an explanation.

Answer (score 15):

In styles file in base application theme add below mentioned line for all values folder in

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> 
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```