# Android find default background color

Tags: android

I have an app with a simple recyclerview.

The layout is declared as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/contentView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/some_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I notice that on different devices, the recyclerView actually had a different background. In newer devices, the background is just white. On older devices, the background is light gray.

In android studio, the background color is blank in the design view.

So my question is, where does this gray color come from? How can I change it universally to white?

I can obviously just add background:white to this particular view. But is there a way to overwrite the system default?

Comment: Unless you have a tremendous number of RecyclerViews, this is totally an overkill. It's probably related to default system settings that changed throughout the system versions. Just set the background color.

Comment: For me it is #f6f6f6, I achieved it by trial and error. :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are seeing is actually the background of the activity, not the recyclerView, which is transparent by default. The color did change a few times per Android version.

> You can override this in your app theme.
>
> First define the color in values/colors.xml

```
 <resources>
     <color name="background">#FF0000</color> 
 </resources>
```

> Create a themes.xml file in res/values that references that color:

```
<resources>  
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">       
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>  
    </style> 
</resources>
```

> and then in your AndroidManifest.xml specify this as
> the theme for your activities to use.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10157077/4623782

Answer (score 22):

Android default background color

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:colorBackground">
 </RelativeLayout
```

use

```
 android:background="?android:colorBackground"
```

Answer (score 1):

it's because of theme. specify your theme in res/values/style.xml. or set manually in view definition.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/contentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/some_id"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
 />
```

it will give you white background on all device

Comment: Setting the background directly on the layout will cause unnecessary overdraw. It's preferable set background on theme style, as shown on accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The color of the background which is set by default in any android studio project is `#fafafa`