# Changing the overall app theme from a fragment in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, themes

Is it possible to change the theme of the overall app to a dark theme from a fragment? The idea is that I have a switch that can be toggled to swap between a dark/light theme. This is all being done within a fragment, so I'm starting to get a little bit confused. Is this at all possible>

Here is that listener:

```
    Switch switchTheme = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switchTheme);

    switchTheme.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         //   switchDark(getView(), isChecked);
            TextView txt = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lblDark);
            if (isChecked) {
                txt.setText("checked");
                // switchDark(getView(), isChecked);
                (MainActivity) getActivity().getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.AppThemeDark, true);
            }
            else{
                txt.setText("unchecked");
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is my styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<!-- colors for the dark theme -->
<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/darkColorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppThemeDark.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Dark.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.Dark.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat" />
```

And here is my colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="colorGrey">#D3D3D3</color>
    <color name="colorTransparent">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorLearned">#32CD32</color>
    <!-- app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml -->
    <color name="darkColorPrimary">#1e2756</color>
    <color name="darkColorPrimaryDark">#141831</color>
    <color name="darkColorAccent">#2aac4b</color>
</resources>
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Is there a way that I can access the styles.xml and color.xml through the code and manually change the colors myself?
For instance, can I literally just do something like `getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent) = "FFFFFF";`?

**Update** What I have done now is created a function inside of the main activity, which is this:

```
public void ToggleTheme(boolean isChecked){
    if (isChecked) {
        this.getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.AppThemeDark_NoActionBar, true);
    }
    else{
        this.getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.AppTheme, true);
    }
}
```

It is then called inside the fragment like such:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);


    Switch switchTheme = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switchTheme);

    switchTheme.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         //   switchDark(getView(), isChecked);
            TextView txt = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lblDark);
            if (isChecked) {
                txt.setText("checked");
                // switchDark(getView(), isChecked);
               // getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).ToggleTheme(isChecked);
            }
            else{
                txt.setText("unchecked");
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).ToggleTheme(isChecked);
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

It seems to change the theme, but keeps the background as white. I have checked and my colors are indeed set to darker colors that should take effect.

Comment: You should make two themes then (MainActivity) getActivity().setTheme(R.style.DarkThemeHere);

Comment: I will update my question with what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way to switch theme by defining them on the styles and just calling the style name to be set, instead of setting each style/color manually.

And to set your background to white, try to add this code inside the style you want to change:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
```

reference: [Android - how to set background color of all screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10157077/9038584)