# When I set android background to white, tablayout and menu items background also turned white

Tags: android, background-color, android-tablayout, menu-items

I'm new to android. I wanted to set the app's background to white so I specified this in style file in app theme. But after doing so what I found is my app's tab layout and menu items background also turned to white. I have no idea what to do. Tried to find the solution but couldn't found.

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<!-- THIS IS THE VIEW PAGER WIDGET, WHICH IS BASICALLY A CONTAINER OR PARENT FOR FRAGMENTS.
     IT GETS ITS SUPPLIES FROM PAGER ADAPTER. :) -->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_stock"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_sale"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_purchase"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>

    <!-- COLOR FOR STOCK FRAGMENT' SUB HEADINGS -->
    <color name="colorSubHeading">#03A9F4</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>

</resources>
```

In the end I'd like to mention that I removed action bar and instead using toolbar. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `android:background` in your styles it affects (nearly) everything I guess. Simply set `android:background="@color/white"` to your root LinearLayout of your activity_main.xml like

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

and it should work as you want.

---

Edit:

If you want to set the background of all activities, see [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10157077/2170795).

Basically you create a `themes.xml`, add a theme and a value for `android:windowBackground` and speficy the theme either for every single Activity you want or for the entire App in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file via `android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"`.

Comment: That's what I thought but suppose there are many activities then in that case I don't think it's a good idea to go to every activity n set the background to white. Isn't there any efficient way to do it?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you wanted to change it for all activities. See the edited information of my answer :)

Comment: Thanks I'll try it cause I shut down my laptop :) . I think it's right.

Comment: I have one problem which I just encountered n which is that I want my tab layout to be elevated by 8dp but when I set d attribute there's no effect. Why any suggestions?

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thanks! Could you please also look at another question of mine which is regarding communication between two fragments in view pager? It would be really nice of you.