# change background of page in theme

Tags: android, colors, themes, android-theme, androidx

I want to change my window background in my theme like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

But there is no change in page.
I tried:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

too.

But all backgrounds change .but i want to change just activity background.

Comment: you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156816/android-how-to-set-background-color-of-all-screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only in one you need to define another style class and there to import to your layout file.

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
 style="@style/MainLayout">
</LinearLayout>

<style name="MainLayout">
   Here you define your background color
</style>
```

Comment: @OmidRezaHeidari No problem glad to help you.