# Android Layout background image and colour

Tags: android, android-layout

what would i need to add to this so that i have a background image and a background colour for main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="330dp"
android:layout_height="600dp"
android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background"
>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to simply fill the parent and then set your background image accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
>
```

Comment: Question is he need background Image and color not only background image that fills whole layout.

Comment: answering my own question which wasnt even the correct answer, to the question I asked. 2 years later android:background="@color/white" in strings.xml add <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748830/how-to-change-background-color-in-android-app