# a random number generator in java eclipse with change color of screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse, random

how i can make random number "double"  generator in java eclipse between 0.8 and 4.5 and change color of the screen  :

1)If the RANDOM value is over 3.5, as soon as the value comes to the screen,the page will be red, when it is between 2.5 and 3.5 it will be orange, when it is between 1.2 and 2.5 it will be yellow and when it is between 0.8 and 1.2 it will be green

2)When the RANDOM  value is over  3.5,there should be sent  SMS to the number you specified before(normally this number belongs to the hospital or the doctor).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating random doubles generate integers between 8 and 45 and divide them to 10. You can use this method to generate numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/363692/891194

I assume you want to change the background of an Android app: [How to change background color in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748830/how-to-change-background-color-in-android-app)

This thread explains how to send an sms: [Send SMS in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967448/send-sms-in-android)