# Unexpected text found in layout file

Tags: android, iphone

> Unexpected text found in layout file android:backround="#252525">

I keep getting this error... I'm trying to make an alarm clock app, because I want one that fits how I would like it! If anyone else has had this issue or knows a fix please make sure to comment. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you're missing a "g" in `background`.

Comment: http://i60.tinypic.com/140hgzt.png

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you got a typo . which is a syntax error. **Do** this way:

`<android:background="#252525">`

For further info, refer :

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748830/how-to-change-background-color-in-android-app)
- [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Comment: I did that Oblivion, now it says "Tag start is not closed"

Comment: The end of your tag needs to end either with /> or needs to end with a closing tag with the name of the widget such as, <TextView android:background="#252525"></TextView>. For widgets that don't have children, the preferred method is to have it look like <TextView android:background="#252525"/>

Comment: sorry fro the delayed reply, please do edit the question with complete info