# Change activity background dynamically

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing a weather app where I wish to change my activity background as the weather changes like night to day or day to night.I seemed unable to find answers.
A little help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748830/how-to-change-background-color-in-android-app

Comment: draw everything in your custom `Drawable` class

Comment: pskink,could you elaborate that ?

Comment: make a custom `Drawable` class and use it in any View by callimg `View#setBackground`

Comment: psink,sorry to bother you again,I am new here and could you give me a link for guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
layout.setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimg));
} else {
layout.setBackground(R.drawable.yourimg);
}
```

Comment: Did you test `layout.setBackground(R.drawable.yourimg);`? setBackground expect **Drawable**, not  **int** parameter

Comment: It did work,but I made a bit my own modification.Cheers

Comment: Please if you find our help valuable, mark the question as solved ;)

Comment: Happy to help you. For getDrawable(int), it's deprecated.

Comment: Hi @Cyborg91 Can you mark my answer as accepted? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your Activity `onCreate()`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //...
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    boolean isNight = hour < 6 || hour > 18;

    int currentDrawable = isNight ? R.drawable.night : R.drawable.day;
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, currentDrawable);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        decorView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    else
        decorView.setBackground(drawable);
}
```

Hope this helps!!