# How to change inactive color icon on BottomBar

Tags: android, colors, navigation, bottombar

I can change the active color with this code:

```
bottomBar.setActiveTabColor
```

But I don't know how to change the inactive color. I'm searching a lot but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If bottomBar is a view then it should backgroundcolor attribute 
android:background="@color/white"
Details

[How to change background color in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748830/how-to-change-background-color-in-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [BottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) library then there is a method:

[`public void setInActiveTabColor(@ColorInt int color)`](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/blob/master/bottom-bar/src/main/java/com/roughike/bottombar/BottomBar.java#L468)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using [Roughike's bottombar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar), you can set the backgroundcolor of a specific tab by using the following line:

```
bottomBar.getTabAtPosition(0).setBackgroundColor(backgroundColorInt);
```

When you use this line multiple times for each tab, you can change the backgroundcolor of the whole tab.