# Designing an Android App with infrared background light

Tags: java, android, android-layout

everyone,

I'd like to design a android app with infrared background light. (Invisible light)

Is there any method to control the background light in certain wavelength(frequency)?

Also, I want to keep it working in background after user opened it.
I mean that it will change the background light of users' phones until they close my app completely.

Since I could only find 
visible background light codes

```
android:background="@color/white"

<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

from this
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748830/how-to-change-background-color-in-android-app)

Thanks you for any suggestions.

Comment: Please name any Android device ever made that has a display that is capable of emitting in the infrared spectrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this is possible, because the leds used for screen backlights are designed to create a single wavelenght of light and cannot be varied, the colors are created by the pixels. To create an infrared light you may use dedicated light emitting diodes.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks a lot for your answer!!!
I have never thought of that.