# How do I change the background of a button in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-button

This is how the button looks right now:

[image: Current Button]

`android:background= "@color/white"` does not change anything.

Code:

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Button"
            android:background="@color/white"/>
```

Comment: android:background="@drawable/button_selector"

Answer (score 1):

Use `app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"`

If you want to use a selector, you will need to have `android:background="@drawable/your_button_selector_id"` as the button background for the selector to work.

Selector:

```
   <selector xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_selected="true" />

 <item android:drawable="@color/black" android:state_selected="false" /> </selector>
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But button_selector doesn't work. <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="Button"/>

Comment: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--released state. -->
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/black" android:width="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

Comment: I did everything as you said, but unfortunately it doesn't work((

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a color just use the **`app:backgroundTint`** attribute:

```
<Button
    app:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>
```

If you just need rounded corners with a stroke, you don't need a drawable.

For it use:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:cornerRadius="16dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:strokeColor="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, I understand the background property doesn't work ?

Comment: @АнтонКобелев You can use it if you need. Use `app:backgroundTint="@null"` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add value for white in your `colors.xml`?
if not open `colors.xml` and add

`<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>`

Full Explanation here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749027/7174681

Comment: Yes, I added colors to the file.xml <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>. It still doesn't work.