# Android: How to change the default shape of a button?

Tags: android, button

Is it possible to change the default shape (i.e rectangular) of the button (normal button as well as imagebutton) to something else maybe like star or a triangle in Android? Any tutorials or sample code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on how you define "shape".

Visually, you change the shape by changing the button background resource. See [this previous SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173936/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-view).

However, I haven't tried this with something non-rectangular, so it is possible that while it will look like a star, the "hot zone" for clicks might still be the original rectangle.

You might look at the implementation of `RatingBar` in the Android open source code, which uses stars, and see if they do anything unusual.

Comment: Actually I want to have an imagebutton in the shape of a star, which can register clicks as well, being a button.