# How can I get color-int from color resource?

Tags: android, colors, android-resources

Is there any way to get a color-int from a color resource?

I am trying to get the individual red, blue and green components of a color defined in the resource (R.color.myColor) so that I can set the values of three seekbars to a specific level.

Answer (score 1075, accepted):

You can use:

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.idname);
```

Check here on how to define custom colors:

http://sree.cc/google/android/defining-custom-colors-using-xml-in-android

**EDIT(1):**
Since `getColor(int id)` is **deprecated** now, this must be used :

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
```

(added in support library 23)

**EDIT(2):**

Below code can be used for both pre and post Marshmallow (API 23)

```
ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.your_color, null); //without theme

ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.your_color, your_theme); //with theme
```

Comment: what about android.R.color.some_color :-(

Comment: @Blundell uhh, dunno if you need it now but this works for `android.R.color.some_color` too e.g.: `getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright)` (at least, on API 17)

Comment: How is the performance of this? Is it worth caching the result so I don't have to look it up every time, or does Android do that internally?

Comment: @karl don't prematurely optimise. It's not a long running operation, and given the param is an ID, it's likely a simple lookup. [Resources src](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java) if you wanted to have a look

Comment: @RestInPeace extract it to a method `int getMyColor() { ... }`. You can keep the color in a variable if the verbosity is impacting clarity of your code - I wouldn't do it for performance reasons though

Comment: This call was deprecated in API23. But, you can call `getResources().getColor(R.color.idname, null);` instead

Comment: getColor() is now deprecated, you can use: ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);

Comment: I realize you aren't the one who made the edits, but what is the difference between `ContextCompat` and `ResourcesCompat`? If there is no practical difference, it would be less confusing if you removed one of them from your answer.

Comment: Why does Google feel the need to deprecate a perfectly good function for that awful app compact library. It sucks, have both.

Comment: @Andrew I agree. Especially since I am using APKBuilder which doesnt have any support or compatibility libraries.

Comment: I am perpetually in awe of the atrociousness of this platform...  at a loss for words.

Comment: getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color) is now deprecated. You might use getColor(R.color.your_color) directly

Answer (score 130):

Based on the new **Android Support Library** (and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int)) update), now you should call:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.name.color);
```

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int)):

```
public int getColor (int id)
```

This method was deprecated in **API level 23**.
Use getColor(int, Theme) instead

It is the same solution for `getResources().getColorStateList(id)`:

You have to change it like this:

```
ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(),id);
```

**EDIT 2019**

Regarding `ThemeOverlay` use the context of the closest view:

```
val color = ContextCompat.getColor(
  closestView.context,
  R.color.name.color
)
```

So this way you get the right color based on your ThemeOverlay.

Specially needed when in same activity you use different themes, like dark/light theme. If you would like to understand more about Themes and Styles this talk is suggested: [Developing Themes with Style](https://chris.banes.dev/talks/2019/developing-themes-with-style/)

[image: Nick Butcher - Droidcon Berlin - Developing Themes with Style]

Comment: For those wondering what to fill in as the theme in the new method, `Theme` can be passed as null, so just call `getColor(R.color.my_color, null)` if you're unsure what theme to pass in.

Comment: hmm... this is what everyone says but i can't get it to work. Do i have to initialize context? Currently I get "cannot resolve symbol 'context'"

Comment: To make sure that you are doing it right, try calling it inside the onCreate of the activity, than to get context  you need to call getContext() or just "this"

Answer (score 43):

## Define your color

*values/color.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- color int as #AARRGGBB (alpha, red, green, blue) -->
    <color name="orange">#fff3632b</color>
    ...
    <color name="my_view_color">@color/orange</color>

</resources>
```

## Get the color int and set it

```
int backgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_view_color);
// Color backgroundColor = ... (Don't do this. The color is just an int.)

myView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
```

## See also

- [How to set background color of a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173936/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-view)
- [Color docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)
- [Color Style Design docs](http://developer.android.com/design/style/color.html)

Comment: can you only use `getResources()` in an `Activity` or `Fragment` ?

Comment: @Zapnologica, see the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666589/using-getresources-in-non-activity-class) for thoughts on using `getResources()` outside of an Activity or Fragment.

Comment: @Zapnologica no. `getResources()` is also available as a public API on anything implementing Context and also on Views.

Answer (score 12):

Found an easier way that works as well:

```java
Color.parseColor(getString(R.color.idname));
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't realise you could get the color as a string in this way. I don't think it's easier, but it's interesting 

Answer (score 11):

## Best Approach

As @sat answer, good approach for getting color is

```
ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.your_color, null);
```

or use below way when you don't have access to `getResources()` method.

```
Context context  = getContext(); // like Dialog class
ResourcesCompat.getColor(context.getResources(), R.color.your_color, null);
```

## What i do is

```
public void someMethod(){
    ...
    ResourcesCompat.getColor(App.getRes(), R.color.your_color, null);
}
```

**It is most simple to use anywhere in your app! Even in Util class or any class where you don't have Context or getResource()**

## Problem (When you don't have Context)

When **you don't have `Context` access**, like a method in your `Util` class.

Assume below method without Context.

```
public void someMethod(){
    ...
    // can't use getResource() without Context.
}
```

Now you will pass `Context` as a parameter in this method and use `getResources().`

```
public void someMethod(Context context){
    ...
    context.getResources...
}
```

So here is a **Bonus unique solution** by which you can access resources from anywhere like `Util class` .
Add `Resources` to your `Application` class or Create one if does not exist.

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.res.Resources;

public class App extends Application {
    private static App mInstance;
    private static Resources res;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
        res = getResources();
    }

    public static App getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public static Resources getResourses() {
        return res;
    }

}
```

Add name field to your `manifest.xml` `<application` tag. (If not added already)

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        ...
        >
        ...
    </application>
```

Now you are good to go. Use `ResourcesCompat.getColor(App.getRes(), R.color.your_color, null);` anywhere in app.

Answer (score 9):

If your current min. API level is 23, you can simply use `getColor()` like we are using for `getString()`:

```
//example
textView.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.green));
// if context is not available(ex: not in activity) use with context.getColor()
```

If you want below API level `23`, just use this:

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
```

But note that `getResources().getColor()` is deprecated in API Level `23`. In that case replace above with:

```
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this /*context*/, R.color.green)) //Im in an activity, so I can use `this`
```

[ContextCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat): Helper for accessing features in [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

If You want, you can constraint with `SDK_INT` like below:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    textView.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.green));
} else {
    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I updated to use `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);` but sometimes (On some devices/Android versions. I'm not sure) that causes a NullPointerExcepiton.

So to make it work on all devices/versions, I fall back on the old way of doing it, in the case of a null pointer.

```
try {
    textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.text_grey_dark));
}
catch(NullPointerException e) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        textView.setTextColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.text_grey_dark));
    }
    else {
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_grey_dark));
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use the old version in all cases, or if you are checking the version anyway, use the new API `Resources.getColor(int, Theme)` if you can? You should not catch runtime exceptions.

Comment: Just OCD I suppose. ContextCompat, to me seems to be the future proof way of doing it, and therefore the right way.
So my approach is, do it the right way. And if that fails (on old devices or whatever), do it the old way.
Why should I not catch exceptions at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

For more information on another use-case that may help surface this question in search results, I wanted to apply alpha to a color defined in my resources.

Using @sat's correct answer:

```
int alpha = ... // 0-255, calculated based on some business logic
int actionBarBackground = getResources().getColor(R.color.actionBarBackground);
int actionBarBackgroundWithAlpha = Color.argb(
        alpha,
        Color.red(actionbarBackground),
        Color.green(actionbarBackground),
        Color.blue(actionbarBackground)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
```

in activity

```
ContextCompat.getColor(actvityname.this, R.color.your_color);
```

in fragment

```
ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.your_color);
```

for example:

```
tvsun.settextcolour(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.your_color))
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing colors from a non-activity class can be difficult. One of the alternatives that I found was using `enum`. `enum` offers a lot of flexibility.

```
public enum Colors
{
  COLOR0(0x26, 0x32, 0x38),    // R, G, B
  COLOR1(0xD8, 0x1B, 0x60),
  COLOR2(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x72),
  COLOR3(0x64, 0xDD, 0x17);


  private final int R;
  private final int G;
  private final int B;

  Colors(final int R, final int G, final int B)
  {
    this.R = R;
    this.G = G;
    this.B = B;
  }

  public int getColor()
  {
    return (R & 0xff) << 16 | (G & 0xff) << 8 | (B & 0xff);
  }

  public int getR()
  {
    return R;
  }

  public int getG()
  {
    return G;
  }

  public int getB()
  {
    return B;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Recent working method:

```
getColor(R.color.snackBarAction)
```

Answer (score 0):

or if you have a function(string text,string color) and you need to pass the Resource Color String you can do as follow

```
String.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.enurse_link_color))
```

Answer (score -2):

In kotlin just use this in your activity

```
R.color.color_name
```

ex-

```
mytextView.setTextColor(R.color.red_900)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Get a warning `Should pass resolved color instead of resource id here: getResources().getColor(R.color.Black)`