# How do I get a color id with a known color name

Tags: android

I have some colors defined in `/values/colors.xml`.

How can I programmatically get the id of a certain color e.g. `R.color.my_color` if I know the name of the color.

Comment: You can use : **getResources().getColor(R.color.idname);**

Comment: Is this something you are looking for? [Get color-int from color resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271387/get-color-int-from-color-resource)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
public int getColorByName( String name ) {
    int colorId = 0;

    try {
        Class res = R.color.class;
        Field field = res.getField( name );
        colorId = field.getInt(null);
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return colorId;
}
```

and in your case `name` is `my_color`:

```
getColorByName("my_color");
```

Comment: I get 0 as a color id when I use this code

Answer (score 3):

There is a dedicated method in [`Resources`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) called [`getIdentifier`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).
It's the "normal" way of achieving what you search.

Try

```
final int lMyColorId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("my_color", "color", this.getPackageName());
```

where `this` is an `Activity` or any `Context` subclass reference. (Replace by `getActivity()` if needed.)
This is said to be slow but imo, this shouldn't be slower than accesing fields through the reflection mechanism the accepted answer suggests.

Example of use for some resource types are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476470/3465369).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This has been updated. And by the way as my answer was right, yet incomplete, you have no legitimacy in downvoting it. Especially thinking it's my first answer on this site, such behaviour is very discouraging.

Comment: For your information I didn't down vote you. I just reviewed your answer and guide you to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

once you have the `Context` you can call `getResources()`-- to get `Resources` reference and thereafter query it to get both `color` and the `id` of the resource.

Answer (score 0):

I found the accepted answer is not working as when I tried to set the background of an `ImageView` it was not setting the right color to it. But then I tried setting the background as resource and it worked perfectly.

So in case of any other confusions, I just want to copy the answer of @MarcinOrlowski and put all these together here.

So here's the function using reflection to get the resource id of the color.

```
public int getColorByName(String name) {
    int colorId = 0;

    try {
        Class res = R.color.class;
        Field field = res.getField(name);
        colorId = field.getInt(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return colorId;
}
```

So now you can get the resource id simply by calling this.

```
int resourceId = getColorByName("my_color");
```

And while you're setting this color using the resource id you've got here, you need to do this.

```
myImageView.setBackgroundResource(resourceId);
```

I tried setting `myImageView.setBackgroundColor(resourceId)` which was not working.