# Android resource not found exception onPageScrolled

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I got the following exception when trying to change the background of pages inside a `ViewPager` in the `onPageScrolled` method. I have edited the question in order to make it more clear.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1245)
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:899)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor(ContextCompat.java:413)
                                                                            at com.noel.material_onboarding.OnboardingActivity.color(OnboardingActivity.java:113)
                                                                            at com.noel.material_onboarding.OnboardingActivity.access$200(OnboardingActivity.java:29)
                                                                            at com.noel.material_onboarding.OnboardingActivity$1.onPageScrolled(OnboardingActivity.java:86)
```

First I create the slider objects, this includes setting up the background color:

```
addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .description("This is a test")
            .backgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
            .build());
    addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .description("This is a test 2")
            .backgroundColor(R.color.green)
            .build());
    addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .description("This is a test 3")
            .backgroundColor(R.color.orange)
            .build());
    addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .description("This is a test 4")
            .backgroundColor(R.color.orange)
            .build());
```

Here's a link to the [SlideFragmentBuilder](https://github.com/NoelOmo/material-onboarding/blob/master/main/java/com/noel/material_onboarding/fragment/SlideFragmentBuilder.java) on github and the [Fragment class itself](https://github.com/NoelOmo/material-onboarding/blob/master/main/java/com/noel/material_onboarding/fragment/OnboardingFragment.java)

Here's my onPageScrolled method:

```
 mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
           int colorUpdate = (Integer) evaluator.evaluate(positionOffset,  color(mOnboardingAdapter.getItem(position).backgroundColor()), color(mOnboardingAdapter.getItem(position + 1).backgroundColor()));
            mViewPager.setBackgroundColor(colorUpdate);


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Window window = getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(colorUpdate);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            btnFinish.setVisibility(position == mOnboardingAdapter.getLastItemPosition() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            btnNext.setVisibility(position == mOnboardingAdapter.getLastItemPosition() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

The color() method that is used

```
private int color(@ColorRes int color){
    return ContextCompat.getColor(this, color);

}
```

Basically, I just need the background of one page to fade in as the user swipes to another page.

Comment: You called `color(0)`, and your error says it isn't happy about that

Comment: `mOnboardingAdapter.getItem(position + 1)` seems to have its attribute that is returned by `backgroundColor()` not initialized

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 could you please expound more on this, I have added a bit of more information to the question to make it more clear, how will I initialize the item at position + 1 ?

Comment: I'm just pointing out what the error says... The integer is 0, and that resource is not found. Add some Log statements to debug. I'm not sure you are even getting the color correctly  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271387/get-color-int-from-color-resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I went through the docs and found an important thing I was missing out on:

> int: Position index of the first page currently being displayed. Page position+1 will be visible if positionOffset is nonzero.

Basically the app was crushing on the second screen after the positionOffset went back to zero. See this is how it works:
On the first screen the positionOffset is zero and the position of the page is also zero, however position + 1 is not available since the positionOffset is zero. I solved this by adding the following statement to check whether the Offset is zero or not:

```
positionOffset != 0.0 ? position + 1 : position
```

This is how the onPageScrolled method looks like:

```
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

           int colorUpdate = (Integer) evaluator.evaluate(positionOffset,  color(mOnboardingAdapter.getItem(position).backgroundColor()), color(mOnboardingAdapter.getItem(positionOffset != 0.0 ? position + 1 : position).backgroundColor()));
            mViewPager.setBackgroundColor(colorUpdate);


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Window window = getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(colorUpdate);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
Color.parseColor(mOnboardingAdapter.getItem(position + 1));
```

and don't forgot to remove integer cast

```
(Integer)
```

And i think that

```
mOnboardingAdapter.getItem(position + 1)
```

is a null value (not initialized)

Comment: Hi could you please tell me how I would initialize this `mOnboardingAdapter.getItem(position + 1)` I have updated the question with more information, hope this helps

Comment: Ok can you tell me why you are using addOnPageChangeListener not OnPageChangeListener ??

Comment: And i think its getItemPosition(position);
not getItem()

Comment: getItemPosition() would return the position of the item, what I need is getItem(position) in order to return the fragment object at that position. The object can then be used to get the background color.

Comment: Ok @NoelOmondi then you have to pass the position using Instance,
    public static OnboardingFragment newInstance(SlideFragmentBuilder builder, int position) {}