# Resources Not Found Exception on a getColor method

Tags: java, android, exception, colors, android-resources

I am using a third party library to create an intro using "slides"(fragments). However, i get the `ResourcesNotFoundException` that you can see below.

I don't know where this `getColor` method mentioned in the exception is at. Could it be thrown from the `backgroundColor()` attribute of each slide?

Here's my code:

```
public class Tutorial extends MaterialIntroActivity {

private Integer[] tutorialImages = {
        R.mipmap.image_main,
        R.mipmap.image_long_tap,
        R.mipmap.image_menu_slide,
        R.mipmap.image_auto_save,
        R.mipmap.image_data_security,
        R.mipmap.image_donation,
        R.mipmap.image_tutorial
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .title("Main Screen")
            .description("Search through the entire Dokkan Cards database and find any card you like.")
            .image(tutorialImages[0].intValue())
            .backgroundColor(R.color.mainScreen)
            .build());


    addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .title("Tap & Long-Press Actions")
            .description("Tap on any card icon to view it's details or Long-press on it to add it to either one of your boxes")
            .image(tutorialImages[1].intValue())
            .backgroundColor(R.color.long_tap)
            .build());

    addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .title("Side Menu")
            .description("Swipe from left to right to access a handful of menu options")
            .image(tutorialImages[2].intValue())
            .backgroundColor(R.color.side_menu)
            .build());

    addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .title("Auto-Save")
            .description("This app saves your box data automatically when you close the app so that you don't have to worry about saving manually")
            .image(tutorialImages[3].intValue())
            .backgroundColor(R.color.auto_save)
            .build());

    addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .title("Data Security")
            .description("Your data is 100% safe since it cannot be accessed by anyone else.All data are stored locally on your device and not on a server or cloud")
            .image(tutorialImages[4].intValue())
            .backgroundColor(R.color.data_security)
            .build());

    addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .title("Donations")
            .description("Although donations are not mandatory, they help a lot in the app's development process. You can submit your donation via the website tab in the app's side menu.")
            .image(tutorialImages[5].intValue())
            .backgroundColor(R.color.donations)
            .build());

    addSlide(new TutorialDisclaimerSlide());

    addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .title("That's it")
            .description("That's the end of this tutorial.You can access it at any time from the top right corner of the app")
            .image(tutorialImages[6].intValue())
            .backgroundColor(R.color.tutorial_end)
            .build());
}
}
```

Here is the colors.xml file:

```
<resources>

<!-- MAIN SCREEN PALLET -->
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

<!-- USER BOX GLB PALLET -->
<color name="colorPrimaryGLB">#016695</color>
<color name="colorSecondaryGLB">#0378ad</color>

<!-- USER BOX JP PALLET -->
<color name="colorPrimaryJP">#991b1b</color>
<color name="colorSecondaryJP">#9e2d2d</color>

<!-- NAVIGATION MENU PALLET -->
<color name="NavigationDrawerHeader">#6F0AB7</color>
<color name="NavActionBarTextColor">#FFFFFF</color>

<!-- CARD DETAILS PALLET -->
<color name="cardDetailsTextColor">#3F54BF</color>

<!-- ABOUT PAGE [SUB-PAGES] PALLET -->
<color name="Contributors_background">#b01818</color>

<!-- Tutorial PALLET -->
<color name="mainScreen">#283593</color>
<color name="long_tap">#0277BD</color>
<color name="side_menu">#27ae60</color>
<color name="auto_save">#2c3e50</color>
<color name="data_security">#34495e</color>
<color name="donations">#7f8c8d</color>
<color name="tutorial_end">#00838F</color>

<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

This is the exception I get:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.dcv.spdesigns.dokkancards, PID: 7958
     android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
         at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
         at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:918)
         at android.content.Context.getColor(Context.java:508)
         at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor(ContextCompat.java:409)
         at agency.tango.materialintroscreen.MaterialIntroActivity.color(MaterialIntroActivity.java:427)
         at agency.tango.materialintroscreen.MaterialIntroActivity.getButtonsColor(MaterialIntroActivity.java:423)
         at agency.tango.materialintroscreen.MaterialIntroActivity.access$1300(MaterialIntroActivity.java:44)
         at agency.tango.materialintroscreen.MaterialIntroActivity$ColorTransitionScrollListener.setViewsColor(MaterialIntroActivity.java:448)
         at agency.tango.materialintroscreen.MaterialIntroActivity$ColorTransitionScrollListener.pageScrolled(MaterialIntroActivity.java:434)
         at agency.tango.materialintroscreen.listeners.ViewBehavioursOnPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(ViewBehavioursOnPageChangeListener.java:54)
         at android.support.v4.view.CustomViewPager.dispatchOnPageScrolled(CustomViewPager.java:1922)
         at android.support.v4.view.CustomViewPager.onPageScrolled(CustomViewPager.java:1896)
         at agency.tango.materialintroscreen.widgets.SwipeableViewPager.onPageScrolled(SwipeableViewPager.java:88)
         at android.support.v4.view.CustomViewPager.pageScrolled(CustomViewPager.java:1834)
         at android.support.v4.view.CustomViewPager.scrollToItem(CustomViewPager.java:695)
         at android.support.v4.view.CustomViewPager.onLayout(CustomViewPager.java:1778)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1166)
         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:851)
         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
         at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2342)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
12-11 14:00:29.413 7958-7958/com.dcv.spdesigns.dokkancards E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong and/or how to trace the `getColor()` method that throws the exception?

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641557/android-resource-not-found-exception-onpagescrolled

Comment: You are crashing on a `getColor()` call. This would not appear to have anything to do with mipmaps.

Comment: tr using .backgroundColor(getResource().getColor(R.color.mainScreen))

Comment: @YoLo Like android studio says, using R.color.string can't be used in this situation and is wrong . I'm searching for the same issue in stack but nothing helps my case.

Comment: please share your colors.xml

Comment: @YoLo alright, it has been added!

Comment: @YoLo any ideas? Still haven't solved it.

Comment: can i have complete code if possible?

Comment: @YoLo what do you mean?I've posted everything that's needed i think :)

Comment: try using images from drawable folder it worked for me

Comment: @YoLo sadly that doesn't fix it for me. I've tried that before but tried it again now, still nothing

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion and the version of the phone/emulator you're running on?

Comment: @MikeSpeed minSDKVersion: 21 , targetSdkVersion: 26, emulator: android 7.0 , phone: s8, android 7.0

Comment: Do you have `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0` (or whatever the current version is) in your build.gradle?

Comment: @MikeSpeed yes i have the compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0' version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem using this issue found on the library :[Solution](https://github.com/TangoAgency/material-intro-screen/issues/66)

All you have to do to fix this exception is:

- Define a `buttonsColor(int color)` attribute for each slide

Here's an example:

```
addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .title("Data Security")
            .description("Your data is 100% safe since it cannot be accessed by anyone else.All data are stored locally on your device and not on a server or cloud")
            .image(R.drawable.image_data_security)
            .backgroundColor(R.color.data_security)
            .buttonsColor(R.color.colorPrimaryGLB)
            .build());
```

**AND**

- Inside each custom fragment slide, `@Override` the required `buttonsColor()` method and `return` your desired `color` value

By returning a color from my buttonsColor() method inside my custom Fragment slide ->

```
    @Override
public int buttonsColor() {
    return R.color.colorPrimaryGLB;
}
```

i managed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a [known issue](https://github.com/TangoAgency/material-intro-screen/issues/65) with the library.

It says:

> you need to necessarily override and specify your own values while
>   creating a custom fragment.

```
 @Override public int buttonsColor() { 
    return R.color.custom_slide_buttons; 
 }
```

Personally, I would extend `MaterialIntroActivity` and then do something like this maybe:

```
@Override
private int color(@ColorRes int color) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return getResources().getColor(color, getTheme()));
    } else {
        return getResources().getColor(color));
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, edited! Yeah make a new subclass that extends MaterialIntroActivity and then change this class to `Tutorial extends MyNewMaterialIntroActivity`

Comment: ok but when i try to @Override the color method it throws an error stating that it does not belong to the superclass. Should MaterialIntroActivity include this method?