# Change colour of countdowntimer

Tags: java, android, timer

I want to change colour of countdowntimer in a specific time. For example, After 50 sec, colour changes greeen to yellow.Could you help me please? Here, you can check my code. Till 50 sec ok.the colour is green. However, after 50th sec, app crashes.

```
       final CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) 
        { 

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            x = millisUntilFinished/1000;
            timer.setText( x +  "    remaining left ");
            if ( 50< x ){
                timer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#32e76b"));

            }
            else{
                timer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("FFE9DD33"));

            }
```

Comment: `app crashes` show crash logs

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5271452/6904440)

Answer (score 0):

Your representation of color is AARRGGBB but is should be #AARRGGBB, you missed **#** in your color so it will throw an IllegalArgumentException exception.

So change like this,

```
timer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE9DD33"));
```

Comment: ahh , Thank you my friend . this is my mistake :(

Answer (score -1):

Try create a colors.xml file inside values folder like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

    <color name="green">#32e76b</color>

    <color name="yellow">yor_yellow_color_code</color>

    <color name="red">yor_red_color_code</color>

</resources>
```

And set like this:

```
final CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) 
        { 

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            x = millisUntilFinished/1000;
            timer.setText( x +  "    remaining left ");
            if ( 50< x ){
                timer.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(your_context,R.color.green)}
            else{
                timer.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(your_context,R.color.yellow);

            }
```

Comment: Sorry, but i couldnt see any difference

Comment: @aliihsanGokalp I updated my answer with new way, check if help you