# When changing the background of app from java when a menu is clicked it doesn't take the right color

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to change the color of the background app when I click a menu for example change background black.
The color it is changing for the first time into transparent so like grey and than stays blue.

I want if the color is red to take red and other colors.
This is my code.

```
 mPopupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, settings);
        MenuInflater menuInflater = mPopupMenu.getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_settings, mPopupMenu.getMenu());
        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPopupMenu.show();
                mPopupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        int id = item.getItemId();
                        if(id == R.id.menu_back_white) {
                            setActivityBackgroundColor(R.color.white);
                        } else if (id == R.id.menu_back_black) {
                            setActivityBackgroundColor(R.color.material_grey_900);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            }
        });

 public void setActivityBackgroundColor(int color) {
        View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        view.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
```

colors

```
<color name="material_grey_900">#ff212121</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

styles

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_900</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_300</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_300</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`view.setBackgroundColor` expects a color value but you give it a resource id.

As stated in [Get color-int from color resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271387/get-color-int-from-color-resource) you have to convert it with e.g. (deprecated variant)

```
getResources().getColor(color);
```

or

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
```

(since support library 23)

Comment: I have added this code getResources and it is working but do you know how to change color for textview and imagebutton ?

Comment: @Spritzig I haven't tried this yet but it should work in the same way for a `TextView`. A `Button` may need a state list drawable. See the docs for details.

Comment: I have fixed for the Image buttons I am trying now with the textview