# Android: Way around View.setAlpha?

Tags: android

So I am trying to adjust the alpha of a view programmatically. As of API 11 there is View.setAlpha(alpha) which works great. My app otherwise supports back to API 4 so is there another way to set the alpha for a view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply an AlphaAnimation to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try View.setBackgroundColor with a color that includes transparency as the first set of hex values before the RGB values (for fully visible red that would be #FFFF0000 - FF for alpha and FF0000 for RGB).

[How to set background color of a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173936/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-view)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not just adjusting the background alpha, but the alpha for the entire view (Which may include images, text, etc.)

Comment: A lot of people are backporting code from Honeycomb and ICS to earlier API levels. If you get your hand on the implementation of setAlpha in API 11 you may be able to figure out something. Not a trivial project, though.