# Get color code from Google Calendar in Android

Tags: android, colors, calendar, google-calendar-api

How can I parse color from `Google event` color code?

I got Google Calendar event like this

I printed my logcat in this format **`event title : calendar color code`**

```
01-12 14:46:40.190: E/(19626): ID : 22 : Happy birthday! : 16437605
01-12 14:46:40.190: E/(19626): ID : 23 : May Day : 13658980
01-12 14:46:40.190: E/(19626): ID : 24 : New Year's Day : 13658980
01-12 14:46:40.190: E/(19626): ID : 25 : Christmas Day : 13658980
```

I tried this like

```
holder.eventColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"
                + data.get(position).calendar_color));
```

so `13658980` is in which format? I think it's not in `ARGB`

Comment: Just guessing, try setBackgroundColor(0xff000000 + data.get(position).calendar_color);

Comment: @DanielFekete it gives compilation error. `0xff000000 + data.get(position).calendar_color` should be int

Comment: I guess its a string, if so you can convert it to int with setBackgroundColor(0xff000000 + Integer.parseInt(data.get(position).calendar_color));

Comment: @DanielFekete I request, please add your answer below. other users generally don't read comments because human love colors. They are just interested in accepted answer.Do helpful for others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data.get(position).calendar_color is a string that you need to convert to integer.

It does not contain alpha so you also need to add 0xff000000, for more information about this, see [How to set background color of a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173936/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-view)

The correct code is:

```
setBackgroundColor(0xff000000 + Integer.parseInt(data.get(position).calendar_color));
```

Answer (score 0):

There was field in table from that you can get the Color of calendar. Using calendar URI you can get the color of and event here is the link for more details

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Calendars.html

**Update**

Ok I have tried your color using same way it parse and display the color. It too light teal color if you increase first two digit or remove it you can get it

```
setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#658980")); // removed alpha color

setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#13658980"));
```

Comment: I already got color using calendar_color but in android there is an issue regarding setting up color.