# change background color of layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have table using table layout. And I have drawable resource for each column. The drawable resource is here.

```
<shape android:shape= "rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/red"/>
      <size android:width="100dp" android:height="50dp"/>
      <padding
          android:left="5dp"
          android:top="5dp"
          android:right="5dp"
          android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

I used  `setBackgroundResource()`
 method. My problem is that I would like to change background color of some columns in run-time depend on the logic. When I use `setBackgroundColor` method,  the drawable resource for that column has gone. Is there any way to do this? Actually I don't want to create another drawable for that column. This may be second way.

Comment: use setBackgroundDrawable?

Comment: It is deprecated. Isn't it?

Comment: perhaps, it says user setBackground(Drawable) in the javadoc but I couldn't find any. Well referring to other people answers, you need to set your project API version to at least 16, then you may use setBackground.

Comment: Here it is: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable).

Comment: Have you tried creating a shape for each color you want and then set the background resource for the column to the shape with the color you desire?

Comment: yes. i got it. I will do my second way. thank anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Background color programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23517879/set-background-color-programmatically)

Comment: or even from 2010: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173936/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-view