# Set Background color programmatically

Tags: android, background-color

I try to set background color programmatically but when I set every one of my colors, the background being black but with any color background being white like the application theme.

```
View someView = findViewById(R.id.screen);
View root = someView.getRootView();
root.setBackgroundColor(color.white);
```

Can you see the code?

Comment: What is `color.white`?

Answer (score 236):

I didn't understand your question ... what do you mean by "when i set every one of my colour"? try this (edit: "#fffff" in original answer changed to "#ffffff"

```
  yourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Answer (score 145):

you need to use getResources() method, try to use following code

```
View someView = findViewById(R.id.screen);
View root = someView.getRootView();
root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(color.white));
```

**Edit::**

getResources.getColor() is deprecated so, use like below

```
 root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
```

Comment: getResources().getColor() is **deprecated**

Comment: in AppCompatActivity you can just use context.getColor() or this.getColor - in fragments you can use getActivity().getColor()

Answer (score 47):

You can use

```
 root.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
```

or

```
 root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Comment: root.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); also

Comment: If using the first example, which bytes map to which color components?  For instance, is it `0xRRGGBBAA`, or `0xAARRGGBB`, or maybe `0xBBGGRRAA` or perhaps `0xXXRRGGBB`?  Doesn't really matter if you're doing white and black, but for basically any other color it's necessary to know this information.

Comment: @Aroth `0xAARRGGBB`.

Answer (score 37):

The previous answers are now deprecated, you need to use `ContextCompat.getColor` to retrieve the color properly:

```
root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.white));
```

Comment: in kotlin 
            root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity?.applicationContext!!, R.color.white));

Answer (score 28):

If you just want to use some of the predefined Android colors, you can use `Color.COLOR` (where `COLOR` is `BLACK`, `WHITE`, `RED`, etc.):

```
myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Otherwise you can do as others have suggested with

```
myView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.myCustomGreen));
```

I don't recommend using a hex color directly. You should keep all of your custom colors in *colors.xml*.

Answer (score 20):

This must work:

you must use **getResources().getColor(R.color.WHITE)** to get the color resource, which you must add in the **colors.xml** resource file

```
View someView = findViewById(R.id.screen);

someView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.WHITE));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you save color code in the colors.xml which is under the values folder,then you should call the following:

```
root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.name));
```

`name` means you declare in the `<color/>` tag.

Comment: This has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it wasn't changing the color because I was **setting the color in my xml resource**.

After delete the line that set the color it worked perfectly programmatically

This is an example I did in a RecyclerView

```
final Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_icon).mutate();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    holder.image.setBackground(drawable);
} else {
    holder.image.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
}
```