# findViewById(R.id.screen) returns null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, view, seekbar

I am trying to change background color of my app when user drags the seekbar.

I have refereed following link : [Set Background color programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23517879/set-background-color-programmatically)

I have following code in `OnSeekBarChangeListener()` :

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    View someView = findViewById(R.id.screen);
    View root = someView.getRootView();
    root.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, r[progress], g[progress], b[progress]));
}
```

It results in following crash :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.getRootView()' on a null object reference
```

Mainactivity class :

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRandomcolors();
        setbuttonclicklistener();
        seebar();
    }
```

`OnSeekBarChangeListener()` is called from `seebar()`

Comment: is your screen is in same layout?

Comment: You don't have view with ID `screen`

Comment: @KDeogharkar how do I know that?

Comment: @BogdanKuštan How can I have a view with screen id ?

Comment: have you set setContentView(your layout)? can you please share more of your code?

Comment: I have called `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: add ID to your layout (activity_main). `android:id="@+id/screen"`

Comment: did you try someView=activity.getCurrentFocus().getRootView() ?

Comment: @BogdanKuštan it worked Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting someView as null. So its giving null pointer exception.

Try changing,

```
 View someView = findViewById(R.id.screen);
```

to

```
 View someView = (View)findViewById(R.id.screen);
```

Can you post your full xml code.

Comment: I think it really does not matter if he converts the null value to 'View'?

Comment: could use: if (someView != null), but you might need this: 
View daddy = (View) (findViewById(R.id.screen)).getParent();