# Android: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color error

Tags: java, android, kotlin, colors

When I try building a project, an error appears, indicated in the name of the topic. directs here:

```
 if (arrList[position].color != null){
            holder.itemView.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(arrList[position].color))
        }else{
            holder.itemView.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(R.color.ColorLightBlack.toString()))
        }
```

if I remove the condition that is written in "else", the project starts without errors. Tried changing the color, nothing changed!

Comment: What is `arrList[position].color)` and `R.color.ColorLightBlack`?

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23517879/set-background-color-programmatically/23518150) we can see that you should write

```
holder.itemView.cardView
    .setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.ColorLightBlack))
```

You are trying to use parseColor, which takes a hexadecimal string as an argument. But calling `toString()` probably isn't making the conversion to hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

`R.color.ColorLightBlack` is an integer value assigned by the Android System. You are trying to pass this value to `parseColor` method which required String. Even if you use toString on `R.color.ColorLightBlack`, the value still remains Integer, hence you are getting the error.

You can update the code like this:

```
if (arrList[position].color != null){
holder.itemView.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(arrList[position].color)) }
else { 
holder.itemView.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(R.color.ColorLightBlack)) 
}
```