# How to change background color via java?

Tags: java, android

Hello I'm a newbie in android development and I am looking forward a way to change the background color.

Here is my code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
// View layout = new View(this);
// layout.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light);
// View root = layout.getRootView();
// root.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark);
View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
view.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
```

Comment: Use setBackgroundResource() instead setBackgroundColor()

Comment: or change the background in the layout file

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set background color of a View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173936/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-view)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the syntax `view.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);`
**Try:**

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: or getResources.getColor(R.color.Red)

Answer (score 1):

view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.example);

Answer (score 0):

used this :-

```
 view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name))
```

This will choose the Marshmallow two parameter method or the pre-Marshmallow method appropriately.